# Bind event to right mouse click

Tags: jquery, css

How can I trigger some action with right click after disabling the browser context menu ?

I tried this . . .

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).bind("contextmenu",function(e){
        $('.alert').fadeToggle();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/2725963/287948

Comment: You're trying to do something _after_ the function returns!

Answer (score 107, accepted):

There is no built-in oncontextmenu event handler in jQuery, but you can do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  document.oncontextmenu = function() {return false;};

  $(document).mousedown(function(e){ 
    if( e.button == 2 ) { 
      alert('Right mouse button!'); 
      return false; 
    } 
    return true; 
  }); 
});
```

Basically I cancel the oncontextmenu event of the DOM element to disable the browser context menu, and then I capture the mousedown event with jQuery, and there you can know in the event argument which button has been pressed.

You can try the above example [here](http://jsbin.com/opare/edit).

Comment: Isn't `$(document)[0]` the same as `document`?

Comment: @configurator, yes it's a typo. Thanks :)

Comment: `"contextmenu"` is now supported!

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in firefox - only chrome. And very likely the numeric value of `e.button` is either browser or hardware specific

Comment: It is better to use e.which (instead of e.button), which will give you the same value to all the browsers.

Comment: Chrome 39 on mac.  e.which does not report 2, e.button == 2 works.  Also 'contextmenu' does not work with addEventListener or with jquery's "on()".  The MDN article also does not work: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/contextmenu

Comment: This answer is invalid, contextmenu is triggered after right mousedown, not right click.

Comment: the line `document.oncontextmenu = function() {return false;};` doesn't make disappear the context menu in chrome v66... any working solution?

Answer (score 50):

**The function returns too early.** I've added a comment to the code below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).bind("contextmenu",function(e){
        return false;
        $('.alert').fadeToggle(); // this line never gets called
    });
});
```

Try swapping the `return false;` with the next line.

Comment: "asked Apr 1 '09" - I assume this is not significant. ;)

Comment: @zourtney What makes you conclude that? The jQuery docs don't mention anything about supporting 'contextmenu'...

Answer (score 15):

Just use the event-handler. Something like this should work:

```
$('.js-my-element').bind('contextmenu', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     alert('The eventhandler will make sure, that the contextmenu dosn&#39;t appear.');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I found this answer here and I'm using it like this.

Code from my Library:

```
$.fn.customContextMenu = function(callBack){
    $(this).each(function(){
        $(this).bind("contextmenu",function(e){
             e.preventDefault();
             callBack();
        });
    }); 
}
```

Code from my page's script:

```
$("#newmagazine").customContextMenu(function(){
    alert("some code");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
document.oncontextmenu = function() {return false;}; //disable the browser context menu
$('selector-name')[0].oncontextmenu = function(){} //set jquery element context menu
```

Comment: `document.oncontextmenu = function() {return false;};` doesn't work at all. Context menu still appears in browser (Chrome 66)

Answer (score 1):

**.contextmenu** method :-

Try as follows

```
<div id="wrap">Right click</div>

<script>
$('#wrap').contextmenu(function() {
  alert("Right click");
});
</script>
```

**.mousedown** method:-

```
$('#wrap').mousedown(function(event) {

        if(event.which == 3){
            alert('Right Mouse button pressed.');
        }  
});
```

Comment: the contextmenu solution is truly elegant

Answer (score 0):

Is `contextmenu` an event?

I would use `onmousedown` or `onclick` then grab the `MouseEvent`'s **button** property to determine which button was pressed (0 = left, 1 = middle, 2 = right).

Answer (score 0):

To disable right click context menu on all images of a page simply do this with following:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    // Disable context menu on images by right clicking
    for(i=0;i<document.images.length;i++) {
        document.images[i].onmousedown = protect;
    }
});

function protect (e) {
    //alert('Right mouse button not allowed!');
    this.oncontextmenu = function() {return false;};
}
```