# jquery right click event?

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to distinguish between left and right mouse click with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206203/how-to-distinguish-between-left-and-right-mouse-click-with-jquery)

in jquery is there a way to distinguish left and right clicks ?