# cross-browser right click plugin with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i've got a context menu plugin that will show a context menu when right clicking an element. but that doesnt work on ajax embedded elements. so i have to use ajax live that trigger the context menu function when it senses a right click.

is there a plugin for jquery detecting right clicks?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this block of code:

```
$("body").mousedown(function(e) {
  var code = ( e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which );

  if( code === 3 ) {
    // do your right-click code here
  }
});
```

Comment: wow..that was a very nice function. worked on chrome, safari and firefox. havent tried in internet explorer. someone could do that for me?

Comment: Note that JavaScript allows: `var code = (e.keyCode || e.which);`

Answer (score 1):

A plugin isn't necessary.  To detect right clicks, check out this previous question: [jquery right click event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646851/jquery-right-click-event)