# Calling Javascript function after selecting "Open link in new tab" and "Open link in new windw"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to call javascript function when user right click on link and selects **"Open link in new tab" and "Open link in new windw"** options. Is there any way to do this? I don't want to use **"oncontextmenu"** and also don't want to customize contextmenu options.

Comment: Strictly speaking, no you can't.  But, I was wondering as to why?  Because I could easily whip up a PHP-based solution (although it couldn't distinguish between the two).  Or, if you're trying to warn the user, we can disable that kind of functionality quite easily.

Comment: Sorry I miss understood.. no you can't as commented above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to capture open link in new tab or window using jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844890/how-to-capture-open-link-in-new-tab-or-window-using-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

**No**, not possible. You have only 2 options to capture the user's right click:

1. Use **oncontextmenu** event:

   ```
   element.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(ev) {
       ev.preventDefault();
       alert('success!');
       return false;  // standard context menu will not pop up
   }, false);
   ```

**OR**

```
<div oncontextmenu="javascript:alert('success!');return false;">
    Lorem Ipsum
</div>
```

2. Use **mousedown** event:

   ```
   $('a').mousedown(function(ev){ 
       if(ev.which == 3){   // 3 -> key code for right-click
           // do your thing
           alert("Right btn clicked");
       }
   }
   ```