# jQuery hide div function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any function for hiding 'DIV's or other html elements on right click, some tutorial, script, simple code javascript or jquery. Example: when is click on link or

tag or 'li' or 'Ul' or 'a' with right click to hide this element... How to do that?

**UPDATE:** Yes, all your solutions is OK but please view this code and why doesn' work:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).on("mousedown", "div, img, span, a", function () { 
    if (event.which === 3)
       $(this).hide();
});
</script>

<?php

$url = 'http://www.kupime.com/';

$data = file_get_contents($url);

$data = '<head><base href='.$url.' target="_blank" /></head>'.$data;




echo $data;


?>
```

And when I click nothing happend. WHY?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646851/jquery-right-click-event

Comment: I'm not a php guy, but I don't see any divs, spans, imgs, or anchors being generated there.

Comment: php generate all this elements:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `event.which` in your mousedown handler to surmise whether the user clicked with the left, or right mouse button.

```
$(document).on("mousedown", "div", function() { 
    if (event.which === 3)
       $(this).hide();
});
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2725963/352552) for more info on `event.which`

**EDIT**

Naturally, if you want to hide elements other than just div, you can comma-delimit them in on's selector

```
$(document).on("mousedown", "div, img, span, a", function () { 
    if (event.which === 3)
       $(this).hide();
});
```

Or if you want to hide *anything* that's right clicked

```
$(document).on("mousedown", "*", function () { 
    if (event.which === 3)
       $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: This is a great solution. But it seems that user1094631 wants to hide every element and not only divs (his comment: "but I need one function for all elements in html"), so it would be a good idea to add a note that 2nd parameter can be "skipped" :).

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#yourDivId").click(function(e) {
 if(e.which === 3) { $(this).hide(); }
});
```

Comment: but I need one function for all elements in html

Comment: yea, or you could add like: $("li, div, a, ...")

Comment: @user1094631 That is a bad idea. If you have 100 elements in a page it will add 100 event handlers + the `$("*")` selector on its own is very slow. Solution by *Adam Rackis* is the way to go - you want to minimize the amount of event handlers.

Comment: Solution of Adam is for div only though

Comment: Is it just me or nobody is noticing that this binds a "click" event which only fires for left mouse button...

Comment: @TeunPronk Just skip the 2nd parameter and it should work for every element: `.on("mousedown", function() {`.

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer right [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206203/how-to-distinguish-between-left-and-right-mouse-click-with-jquery).
That will show you how to know if you clicked it with the right mouse button.

It will turn out to be like this:

```
$("body").children().click(function(e) {
 if(e.which === 3) { $(this).hide(); }
});
```

Comment: `click` is only triggered for left mouse button clicks. You must use `mousedown` to check for right-clicks :).