# Triggering onclick event using middle click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the `onclick` event of a hashed link to open a `<div>` as a pop up. But **the middle click does not trigger the `onclick` event** but only takes the `href` attribute value of the link and loads the URL in a new page. How can I use middle click to open the `<div>` as a popup?

Comment: I still don't understand how the problem was solved, when middle click does not trigger the onclick event.

Comment: @TomášZato Browsers don't fire a 'click' event with a middle-click, but they might fire a 'mouseup' event. Then the javascript framework may bind this to a 'click' action to confuse you. I recommend the reading of http://www.unixpapa.com/js/mouse.html

Answer (score 73, accepted):

**EDIT**

This answer has been deprecated and *doesn't work* on Chrome. You will most probably end up using the [auxclick event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/auxclick_event), but please refer to other answers below.

**/EDIT**

---

beggs' answer is correct, but it sounds like you want to prevent the default action of the middle click. In which case, include the following

```js
$("#foo").on('click', function(e) {
   if (e.which == 2) {
      e.preventDefault();
      alert("middle button"); 
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="foo" href="http://example.com">middle click me</a>
```

[preventDefault()](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/jQuery.Event#event.preventDefault.28.29) will stop the default action of the event.

Comment: Keep in mind that `.live` was deprecated and removed in favor of `.on`

Comment: To get this working in FF use: var evt = e || window.event;

Comment: For me FF works only with mousedown event. Click event calls this thing http://scr.hu/1kig/su5c9

Comment: Is there any cross-browser constant for that `2`?

Comment: @fracz there is a standard, but ofc IE doesn't follow it - middle button has id=4, and right button has id=2. Read about it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10562950/mousemove-and-cross-browser-e-which) and [here](http://www.martinrinehart.com/early-sites/mrwebsite_old/examples/cross_browser_mouse_events.html). Check if libraries you use normalize those IDs.

Comment: @xcy7e웃 - it's not working for me. What is working, though, is changing the eventhandler to either 'mousedown' or 'mouseup'. Tested with FF, Chrome and Edge:
Left click: e.which -> 1; e.button: 0
Middle click: e.which -> 2; e.button: 1
Right click: e.which -> 3; e.button: 2 
=======
IE8: 1/1; 2/4; 3/2

Comment: This no longer works in Chrome 55. See [1](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=255#c160), [2](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/10/auxclick) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41110264/499922)

Comment: How is this a solution when the problem was that middle click does not trigger the click event to begin with?

Comment: .which is deprecated, use .button
Not sure who named it "which" in the first place. I don't know what web devs were doing 10-15 years ago...

Comment: LET IT CROSS-BROWSERS: `...function(e) { e = e || window.event; var b = e.keyCode || e.which; if (b == '2') {...`

Comment: This answer should not be pinned to the top as it is out-of-date and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 65):

For the middle-click / mouse-wheel button to be detected, you have to use the event `auxclick`. E.g:

```
<a href="https://example.com" onauxclick="func()" id="myLink"></a>
```

Then in your script file

```
function func(e) {
  if (e.button == 1) {
    alert("middle button clicked")
  }
}
```

If you want to do it from JavaScript (without using the HTML attribute `onauxclick`), then you `addEventListener` to the element:

```js
let myLink = document.getElementById('myLink')
myLink.addEventListener('auxclick', function(e) {
  if (e.button == 1) {
    alert("middle button clicked")
  }
})
```

```html
<a id="myLink" href="http://example.com">middle click me</a>
```

Checkout the mdn page about the `auxclick` event [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/auxclick).

Comment: note: onauxclick will work but it does not open the link in a new tab...

Comment: This is the only answer that actually works in Chrome. If you need a "click" event for the right mouse button, you can use "contextmenu" (although it's not only fired by right click): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/contextmenu_event

Comment: combining with above answer, you can prevent right click capture by `if(event.button==1)` clause, this is the only working answer.

Comment: Note that you need to use both the `auxclick` event, and to check for the value of `e.button == 1`. I edited the answer.

Comment: Note that it does not work on Safari. https://caniuse.com/auxclick

Answer (score 29):

You can use

[event.button](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Event.button)

to identify which mouse button was clicked.

Returns an integer value indicating the button that changed state.

- 0 for standard 'click', usually left button
- 1 for middle button, usually wheel-click
- 2 for right button, usually right-click

Note that this convention is not followed in Internet Explorer: see 
QuirksMode for details.

The order of buttons may be different depending on how the pointing device has been configured.

Also read

[Which mouse button has been clicked?](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html#button)

> There are two properties for finding
>   out which mouse button has been
>   clicked: which and button. Please note
>   that these properties don’t always
>   work on a click event. To safely
>   detect a mouse button you have to use
>   the mousedown or mouseup events.

```js
document.getElementById('foo').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  console.log(e.button);
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<a id="foo" href="http://example.com">middle click me</a>
```

Comment: I'd recommend using `event.which` as it has been standardized across browsers in the jQuery source - line 2756 - `if ( !event.which && event.button ) event.which = (event.button & 1 ? 1 : ( event.button & 2 ? 3 : ( event.button & 4 ? 2 : 0 ) ));`

Comment: @RussCam However, `MouseEvent.which` is not defined in any spec, but `MouseEvent.button` is defined in DOM L2 Events.

Comment: @Oriol correct, but implemented differently across different browser vendors. The OP tagged the question with jQuery, so that's why I suggested using `event.which` but should have elaborated that `MouseEvent.which` is not part of the official specification.

Comment: @rahul, What about gaming mouses with more than 7 buttons? http://www.egg-tech.com/blog/images/mouse%20buttons.jpg

Comment: Actually, this doesn't work in browsers like Firefox or Chrome, only for primary click. See [1](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=255#c160), [2](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/10/auxclick) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41110264/247696).

Answer (score 13):

This question is a bit old, but i found a solution:

```js
$(window).on('mousedown', function(e) {
   if( e.which == 2 ) {
      e.preventDefault();
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://example.com">middle click me</a>
```

Chrome not fire "click" event for the mouse wheel

Work in FF and Chrome

Comment: I don't want to assume your use case, but I would bet money a lot of people would actually need the 'mouseup' event instead. It works with the middle mouse button as well.

Comment: When I try this in Firefox and Chrome, it does not prevent the default behaviour of opening the link in a new tab, even though `e.preventDefault()` is called.

Answer (score 8):

I usually hate when people offer alternatives instead of solutions, but since solutions have already been provided I'm going to break my own rule.

Websites where the middle-click feature is overridden tend to really, really bug me. I'm usually middle-clicking because I want to open the new content in a new tab while having an unobstructed view of the current content. Any time you can leave the middle-click functionality alone and make the relevant content available through the HREF attribute of your clicked element, I strongly believe that's what you should do.

Comment: but what if you have tabs on your webpage and want the same behaviour as in your browser? middleclick should close an existing tab then.

Answer (score 7):

jQuery provides a `.which` attribute on the event that gives the click button id from left to right as 1, 2, 3.  In this case you want 2.

Usage:

```
$("#foo").live('click', function(e) { 
   if( e.which == 2 ) {
      alert("middle button"); 
   }
});
```

Adamantium's answer will also work but you need to watch out for IE as he notes:

```
$("#foo").live('click', function(e) { 
   if((!$.browser.msie && e.button == 1) || ($.browser.msie && e.button == 2)) { 
     alert("middle button"); 
   } 
});
```

Also remember the `.button` attribute is 0-indexed not 1-indexed like `.which`.

Comment: can i override the functionality of mozilla browser!!
eg on left click it opens a pop up....
but for middle click it is not opening a pop up and a new tab is opened in which the pop up is not opening.. so i want to override a middle click functionality of mozilla....

Comment: Mozilla has a setting to open all popups in a new tab rather than a new window. If the user has this option enabled then I don't *think* there is anything you can do. If this is not what is happening can you post some code or a link to the problem page?

Comment: This doesn't work in browsers like Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 5):

The proper method is to use `.on`, as `.live` has been deprecated and then **removed** from jQuery:

```
$("#foo").on('click', function(e) { 
   if( e.which == 2 ) {
      e.preventDefault();
      alert("middle button"); 
   }
});
```

Or if you want the "live" like feel and `#foo` is not on your page on document start:

```
$(document).on('click', '#foo', function(e) { 
   if( e.which == 2 ) {
      e.preventDefault();
      alert("middle button"); 
   }
});
```

[original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1803868/561731)

Comment: The event `click` does not work for the middle mouse button in browsers like Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: it used to @Flimm

Comment: Yeah. Stack Overflow does not have a good solution for out-of-date answers. I am afraid I have to downvote because "This answer is not useful" any more. What is worse is that the pinned answer can have hundreds or thousands of downvotes because it is out-of-date, and it will still stay pinned forever if the OP is not responding.

Comment: Ask a new question :-) (reference this one saying it is out of date and you want a 2020 answer) . But also can use mousedown/mouseup events maybe?

Comment: Even if I do that, people like me are still going to come across this answer when coming from search engines, and are going to be confused by the pinned wrong answer.

Comment: I can link it in my answer when you have yours (for a as of 2020 go here or something like that :-) )

Answer (score 3):

I know I'm late for the party, but for those still having problems with handling the middle click, check if you delegate the event. In case of delegation, the `click` event does not fire. Compare:

**This works for middle clicks:**

```js
$('a').on('click', function(){
  console.log('middle click');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://example.com">middle click me</a>
```

**This doesn't work for middle clicks:**

```js
$('div').on('click', 'a', function(){
  alert('middle click');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <a href="http://example.com">middle click here</a>
</div>
```

If you still need to track the middle click *using event delegation*, the only way around as stated in the corresponding [jQuery ticket](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11485), is to use `mousedown` or `mouseup` instead. Like so:

**This works for delegated middle clicks:**

```js
$('div').on('mouseup', 'a', function(){
  console.log('middle click');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <a href="http://example.com">middle click me</a>
</div>
```

[See it online here](http://jsfiddle.net/skip405/f9tmk34k/1/).

Comment: Actually, `click` does not work for middle clicks as in your first example.