# Capture and Stop Middle Click

Tags: javascript, events, click, capture

I know - this has been asked before, HOWEVER:
People keep saying "you can't do that in Firefox", etc. etc. (specifically, this answer: [Disabling middle click scrolling with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930875/disabling-middle-click-scrolling-with-javascript))

...then how does this do it?
http://www.lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/

1. It's in Prototype/Scriptaculous, but my Google-fu is failing me.
2. I can't reproduce it in jQuery/MooTools (http://jsfiddle.net/ezSR4/1/)
3. It looks tied to the Prototype implementation of events, but perhaps someone knows better than my quick investigation?

It captures the middle clicks, prevents a new window, and fires the correct event to open the overlay. I'm just not as familiar with Prototype as I am with the other libraries, and hope someone can point out the obvious.

TIA.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

he is using the click event directly on the document object then it checks if it is on one of those picture links

so that would be the solution for right and middle click

```
  document.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    if(e.button == 1){
      e.preventDefault();
      alert(e.button);
    }
  }, true);
```

Comment: ...I feel like an idiot, thanks for the simple clean explanation, now to test it!