# Prevent middle mouse click scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, mouseclick-event

I'm looking for a way to stop the middle mouse click from causing the browser to start scrolling, and showing the little scroll 'compass'.

I have seen [Disabling middle click scrolling with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930875/) however the solution is a bit more hackey than I would like, and doesn't seem like something I could actually use.

**I'm looking for a more definitive "This is how you do it" or "You cannot do that, son".**

I am of course open to hacks and workarounds.

Just because S.O. questions look nicer with code, here is what I am using to close tooltips when right or middle clicking.

```
msg.mousedown(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 2) {   //middle mouse click
        msg.hide();
        e.preventScrolling();   //if only this worked...
    }
    else if (e.which == 3) {   //right mouse click
        msg.hide();
    }
}).bind('contextmenu', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}).click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

*edit: jQuery, JavaScript, whatever, let's just all play nicely now :)*

**Edit 2:**

I'm more interested in preventing the little scroll 'compass' than stopping the page from scrolling. I guess that wasn't very clear from my initial description.

Comment: I very highly advise against breaking basic browser/OS functionality.

Comment: @JAAulde: In some web applications, scrolling might not be meaningful so disabling it can be useful.

Comment: My mouse doesn't even have a middle button! Oh wait, it hasn't got any buttons at all. :)

Comment: @JAAulde The context for this is small popup notifications, I guess you might call them 'Growl style notifications'. I want users to be able to right or middle click on these to dismiss them without the context menu appearing (check!) or the scroll 'compass' appearing.    I HIGHLY doubt anyone is going to be trying to scroll in a <100px message which will never be scrollable.     On principle, I do however agree breaking standard browser/OS functionality should be avoided but there are situations that I feel warrant it.

Comment: I don't want to be argumentative, but if you "HIGHLY doubt anyone is going to be trying to scroll in a <100px message which will never be scrollable," why are you bothering?

Comment: Argumentative, no, 'debatitive', go wild :> I am used to being able to close tabs in my browser with a middle click. I feel that the action 'middle clicking a closeable object/element' should close the object/element. Which I can achieve, however the little leftover scroll 'compass' makes it imperfect. Actually 'scrolling' in the notification isn't an issue. Note this is in the context of a web application where messages and notifications are expected/dealt with often, not a standard web page.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disabling middle click scrolling with javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930875/disabling-middle-click-scrolling-with-javascript)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use:

```
$('body').mousedown(function(e){if(e.button==1)return false});
```

This works on Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/PKpBN/3/

Comment: @pimvdb Why use event attributes when you can bind the event handlers unobtrusively?

Comment: @pimvdb Yes, it works, but it's still inferior to JavaScript event binding.

Comment: Let's change it to jQuery style then.

Comment: @Sime Vidas: if you look at my tags you'll see I am a Mac developer: http://www.apple.com/magicmouse/ :) <— bad joke, sorry

Comment: @pimvdb don't use jQuery just for this. It's like using a car to drive to your neighbors.

Comment: I agree, but putting it in HTML is not preferred either is it?

Comment: @pimvdb If the OP uses jQuery, then a jQuery solution is OK. If not, then just `document.body.onmousedown = function(e) { ... };`

Comment: This is the closest yet to what I wish to achieve - no scroll 'compass' when middle clicking the mouse. Now if only it worked on other browsers!

Comment: `addEventListener("mousedown", function(e){ if(e.button == 1){ e.preventDefault(); } });` worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

tested with the current version of firefox and chrome

```
document.body.onmousedown = function(e) {
    if(e.button == 1) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to include jQuery just for this.

If you are using jQuery, there are already some great answers here. If not, you can use vanilla JS:

```
document.body.onmousedown = function(e) { if (e.button === 1) return false; }
```

Comment: this is vanilla sweet

Answer (score 0):

Try using `return false;` instead of `e.preventScrolling();`

Answer (score -2):

```
document.body.style.overflow=allowScroll?"":"hidden";
```

Comment: I can't seem to get this one to work, any idea what I mightn't be doing correctly? http://jsfiddle.net/2R7tj/

Answer (score -4):

If you want to stop scrolling completely, here is the required code:

```
window.onscroll = function() {
    document.body.scrollTop = 0;
}
```

This will effectively disable the middle button as well..

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/XcBDF/ In Chrome, this disables dragging the scrollbar, or clicking the scroll buttons on the scroll bar, but it does nothing to the middle mouse button, I can scroll and click-scroll just fine. In Firefox it does nothing.

Comment: It did disable scrolling when moving the middle wheel but you're right about clicking it.. maybe in combination with code disabling that click then.