# How to disable mousewheel panning in javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, mousewheel

I have a div, which has

```
.A {
    max-height:100px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

I don't want it to scroll. However I noticed the user can still click down with a mousewheel then move the mouse up or down and it simulates a scroll. The div box goes up and down. How can I disable this?

https://jsfiddle.net/2aoeyfbL/

Thanks

Comment: The div has content and the content scrolls up and down as if the vertical scroll bar is there.

Comment: I added a fiddle which has the problem there too.

Comment: I cant see the problem.I cant scroll inside the div, even with mouse's middle scroller

Comment: I cant scroll on the fiddel

Comment: It does happen sometimes, and im on latest version of chrome.

Comment: its a browser bug then

Comment: Its a bit tricky to do, but you have to click with mouse wheel, then move mouse left of div and outside of the div then go up or down.

Comment: Did you check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5136845/prevent-middle-mouse-click-scrolling)?

Comment: @omega: That's probably windows only. Try this fiddle: Click inside, then hit tab: https://jsfiddle.net/2aoeyfbL/4/

Comment: @sabithpocker: That is also just a hack that does not capture everything.

Comment: It seems to only happen on chrome on windows.

Comment: got you man.. after pressing hard & moving around it did scroll.. but would someone do that

Comment: good, so I'm not going insane.

Comment: I know a **great** solution, just reset scroll position every single frame XD

Comment: @H.B. that actually worked great haha.

Comment: Yes, but it's plain awful.

Comment: I just did this `$('.A').bind("scroll", function(e) { this.scrollTop = 0; });`

Comment: That is much more acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work all the time, even by pressing tab when there is an input box inside the div.

```
$('.A').bind("scroll", function(e) {
    this.scrollTop = 0;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix the position of the div

```
.A {
    max-height:100px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    position:fixed;
}
```

Comment: this will mess up the rest of the page. I only want this to affect the `.A` tags.

Comment: default overflow is coming from the body.If you do not hide the overflow of the body, The default overflow always appears.body is the parent of div.

Comment: .A {
    max-height:100px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    position:fixed;
}