# Issue with onClick() and middle button on mouse

Tags: jquery, onclick, jquery-events

```
<a href="<?=$rowz[0]?>" onClick="countLinks('<?=$row[6]?>','<?=$indexl?>')">[Link <?=$j++?>]</a>
```

The problem is that it doesn't work with middle button on IE or firefox.
In fact, the `countLinks` using middle button is called only with chrome.

I think I need a Jquery function like `mouseup` event, just I don't know how call that function, which it calls `countLinks` with those parameters parameters.

Any help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Triggering onclick event using middle click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795734/triggering-onclick-event-using-middle-click)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're right. You need a `mousedown` or `mouseup` event to determine which mouse button was actually clicked.

But first of all, you need to get rid of that inline-event handler `onclick` and follow the shining road of **unobtrusive javascript**.

Thatfor you need to give that anchor a `id` or `class` tag to identify it (Of course you may also choose to select that anchor with a css selector). Lets assume we have added a class with the name **myClazzz** :)

javascript:

```
$(function(){
    $('.myClazzz').bind('mouseup', function(e){
        switch(e.which){
           case 1:
              alert('Left Mouse button pressed.');
           break;
           case 2:
              alert('Middle Mouse button pressed.');
           break;
           case 3:
              alert('Right Mouse button pressed.');
           break;
           default:
              alert('You have a strange Mouse!');
        }
    });
});
```

The `which` property within a `mousedown` / `mouseup` event handler will contain a number which indicates which mousebutton was clicked.

Comment: +1 but why not `click`? You can also see if clicked button is left, middle or right... Mouseup mousedown might behave differently cross browser.

Comment: @Sinan Y.: that javascript `click` event combines `mousedown` + `mouseup` and fires only on left button clicks.

Comment: uhm... so i need to put for each case (1-2-3) a copy of the same function? and how can i pass parameters (like $row[6] and $indexl) to that function?

Comment: i know that click is the combination of both, anyway my bad i remembered that it was behaving weird, probably i mixed up with sth else, but i tested now and you're definitely right, sorry for text pollution:)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick solution for you, by using some [`html5` attributes](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/)... Actually it was also possible before html5 but it wasn't validating.

**I'd create the links as below:**

`<a class="myClazzz" href="<?=$rowz[0]?>" data-row="<?=$row[6]?>" data-index="<?=$indexl?>">...</a>`

_here we put your parameters to `data` attributes

**and write the js like this:**

```
$(function(){
    //use mouseup, then it doesn't matter which button 
    //is clicked it will just fire the function
    $('.myClazzz').bind('mouseup', function(e){
        //get your params from data attributes
        var row   = $(this).attr("data-row"),
            index = $(this).attr("data-index");

        //and fire the function upon click
        countLinks(row,index);
    });
});
//don't forget to include jquery, before these lines;)
```

Hope this works out. Sinan.

`PS` *myClazzz -> credits goes to jAndy :)*

Comment: uoo...never seen before that syntax on link (i mean data-var stat). i need to learn it :) tomorrow i'll check that function, now in italy (3.00 am) it's a bit late! tnx man

Comment: FYI: `$(this).data('row')` is the same as `$(this).attr('data-row')`

Answer (score 1):

The behavior of this is quite variable by browser.  See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=255#c106 .  According to that, of the ones you asked about:

- "IE doesn't fire a click event if the target is a link, but does fire it if
  another element is clicked even if it's a descendant of a link."
- "Gecko always fires a click event on the document that bubbles and has as
  target the element being clicked."

For Firefox, thus you can do:

```
$( document ).click(
  function ( evt ) {
    // ... evt.which === 2 means middle click
  }
);
```

which is kind of a trick (normally you would listen to events on the link itself), but it works.