# Javascript confirm dialog and middle/right mouse click

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, confirm

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC 3 project, and I want to display a confirmation message before deletion, I've wrote the following line:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ID }, new { onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure?')" })
```

Which is ok and works fine, however when I click middle button on the mouse or right click then choose 'Open Link in New Tab', the record will be deleted without displaying the confirm dialog which is weird!

I have tried the upper code with `onMouseDown`, the dialog displays but no action is happening when I click on OK button! (the record wont be deleted)

My question is how can I display a confirmation message before I delete a record and that link will only respond to left mouse click?

Comment: This should be a POST operation. Never allow a simple link to change data.

Comment: Totally agree with ZippyV you should never to operations that would change the data at your backend using GET.

Answer (score 0):

You should check mouse key on 'onclick' event and then return false if key is left. See useful example: [Issue with onClick() and middle button on mouse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272715/problem-with-onclick-and-middle-button-on-mouse)

Comment: Still not working, it will detect middle & right button click but it will continue to open new tab and delete the record