# Disable mouse middle click event with help of jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to disable mouse middle click event in anchor tag. It works perfectly in Chrome. Here is my code for Chrome implementation:

```
//prevent mouse wheel middle click for chrome 
$(document).on('auxclick', 'a', function (e) {
  if (e.which === 2) { //middle Click 
          return false;
  }
return true;
});
```

**Note:** above the implementation work only for Chrome 55 and their latest version

**Reference auxclick documentation for Chrome:** https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/10/auxclick

**auxclick browser compatibility:**

**Reference Link:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/auxclick

[image]

[image]

Unfortunately i am unable to disable mouse middle click event in rest of browser like Firefox, IE11 & Safari

I am trying to find possibility in rest of browser. Trying mousedown & mouseup event to disable mouse middle click event in rest of browser but those events don't help to achieve my expectation.

Comment: Why would you want this? There might be a valid reason, but the scroll-click is native userinterface (e.g. to quick scroll), be very careful changing that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Disable the Mouse wheel click Button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11392318/how-to-disable-the-mouse-wheel-click-button)

Comment: @Stevm non of the reference not work for me. I am trying to disable in latest version of browsers. clearly explain in my question about that.

Comment: @Martijin they main reason is we need to prevent navigating our website in new tab if we click mouse middle click in anchor tag

Comment: @Martijin i agree the scroll-click is native userinface event but how we able to prevent in chrome not able to prevent in rest of browser. do you any valid reason for this.

Answer (score 1):

The `auxclick` event is an experimental technology and therefor it has limited browser support.

You could use the [mousedown](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/Events/mousedown) event:

```js
$('button').on('mousedown', function(e) {
    if (e.which === 2) {
      console.log('Disabled');
      return false;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click me</button>
```

This should work in all major browsers, though I don't like the idea of changing native behavior.

Comment: Thanks for your response. your code is not full fill our expectation. our expectation is prevent or disable navigation of next tab if we click mouse middle click in anchor tag ((i.e.) <a href="example.com">example</a>). we try this way in anchor tag. the middle click event fire in if loop but not prevent/disable navigate to next tab in all major browser.

Comment: [`MouseEvent.which`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent#properties) is non-standard technology .