# Does the onclick Attribute Catch Middle Clicks?

Tags: javascript, html

I know you can get this working with an event listener, but is it possible to catch middle clicks with the onclick attribute in HTML?

For example:

```
<span onclick="alert('hi');">middle click me<span>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cB8Qv/

Comment: seems to be working on Chrome.

Comment: Why is this a question? Have you tried to middle click in your fiddle?

Comment: I believe the question is what is the official statement .. i could not find one. Every official doc reference to a pointing device and does not provide any knowledge to what button specifically suppose to be click.. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.onclick http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#adef-onclick

Comment: @Jace I tried, it doesn't work for me, the user Class says it works for him

Comment: Works for me in Chrome and IE and FFX...

Comment: @Kirk Fair enough. Works for me, in Chrome.

Comment: I should mention I'm, running Firefox 20.0.1 on Windows 7

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795734/triggering-onclick-event-using-middle-click and http://unixpapa.com/js/mouse.html

Comment: Interesting background on the webkit implementation of the middle click behavior: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=22382

Comment: Doesn't work for me in Firefox Aurora channel. Windows 8 x64.

Comment: doesnt work on FF 19.0.2 on Win7 Pro 64Bit

Answer (score 1):

A middle click is still giving off a click to your system, so yes it does work. Depending on your system this can do weird things such as opening a new window. Not sure how this affects on-clicks. But they will work.

Answer (score 0):

If you put this around your span instead of using the onClick you can also use middle clicks (in all browsers),but its called bad practice .

```
<a href="javascript:alert('hi');">
    <span>middle click me</span>
</a>
```