# Is it possible to capture the scroll wheel click

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I've just written some code, that when the user clicks on a link (I'm using jQuery's `.click()`), they get a modal popup telling them they're being redirected to a different site. This all works fine with a normal left click, however, clicking the link using the middle mouse button to open it in a different tab loads the page straight away rather than showing the modal. Ideally I'd like to show them the modal too, then after the timer finishes open it in a new tab for them.

Is it possible to capture this click too?

Comment: Instead of click examine e.which in .mousedown()

Comment: possible duplicate of [Triggering onclick event using middle click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795734/triggering-onclick-event-using-middle-click)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, It will help

```
$("yourtag").on('mousedown', function(e) { 
   if( (e.which == 1) ) {
     alert("left button");
   }if( (e.which == 3) ) {
     alert("right button");
   }else if( (e.which == 2) ) {
      alert("middle button"); 
   }
   e.preventDefault();
}).on('contextmenu', function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: `live()` has been deprecated for years and doesn't even exist in  newer versions of jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible through simple click event listener:

```
$("#element").bind('click', function(e) { 
   if( e.which == 2 ) {
      e.preventDefault();
      alert("middle button"); 
   }
});
```

just for your information, e.which == 1 will fire for left click and 3 for right click.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
$(document).on("mousedown", "a", function(e) {
   if( e.which == 2 ) {
      e.preventDefault();
      //your code here
   }
});
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code. E.g. `.on(event, selector, handler)` is only helpful if you explain it, because `.on()` is seldom used in examples with more than two arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this answer : [Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qxb4621L/)

```
$("#foo").on('click', function (e) {
    if (e.which == 2) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("middle button");
    }
});
```

[Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795734/triggering-onclick-event-using-middle-click)

Comment: `live()` is deprecated.