# Subscribe to wheel middle click when using mousewheel plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

My javascript app uses both mousewheel (jquery plugin) event and left and right click events:

```
$(document).mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
    if (delta < 0) {
        swipeLeft(nextLink);
        return false;
    } else if (delta > 0) {
        swipeRight(prevLink);
        return false;
    }
});
$("#div")
    .on('contextmenu', function(ev) {
        if (ev.which == 3) {
            ev.preventDefault();   
            swipeRight(prevLink);
        }
    })
    .mousedown(function(ev){
        if(ev.which == 1) {
            swipeLeft(nextLink);
            return false; 
        }
    });
$('#div').click(function(ev){
    if (ev.which == 1) {
        swipeLeft(nextLink);
        return false;
    }
});
```

I want middle click have normal behaviour, i.e. not being interpreted as a mouse wheel event, but the delta value is always 1 when I middle-click.

Is there a way to isolate middle click from mouse wheel turn?

Does the order the mousewheel and click events are defined matter?

Comment: The mouse middle-click is button #3 ... `ev.which === 3` ... maybe you can check for that _before_ checking delta? (just a thought, completely untested)

Comment: There is also [auxclick](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/Events/auxclick) but it's not well supported -- see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41110264/17300) and the answers on it.

Comment: `which === 3` on my first comment may be wrong, I just took that from the question I cited. [MDN MouseEvent.button](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/button) is a more authoritative source for the button values.

Comment: is it possible to define an unique event managing bot click and mousewheel?

Comment: Custom events may help you — see ["Creating and triggering events"](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/) and/or ["Introducing Custom Events"](https://learn.jquery.com/events/introduction-to-custom-events/) for jQuery events, and this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23344816/17300) for brief examples.