# Is there any way to detect middle click in React JS?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, mouseevent

I am trying to find a way to detect middle click event in React JS but so far haven't succeeded in doing so.

In Chrome React's Synthetic Click event does show the button clicked ->

```
mouseClickEvent.button === 0 // Left

mouseClickEvent.button === 1 // Middle but it does not execute the code at all

mouseClickEvent.button === 2 // Right (There is also onContextMenu with event.preventDefault() )
```

Please share your views.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Middle button click event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41110264/middle-button-click-event) with a working accepted answer

Comment: Not a duplicate. The linked question is tagged jquery. This is tagged reactjs. React uses its own synthetic events.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you are using a stateless component:

JS

```
const mouseDownHandler = ( event ) => {
  if( event.button === 1 ) {
    // do something on middle mouse button click
  }
}
```

---

JSX

```
<div onMouseDown={mouseDownHandler}>Click me</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: click !== mousedown  - they are completely different events with completely different behavior.  Use onAuxClick instead.

Answer (score 13):

The modern way of doing it is through the [onAuxClick](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/auxclick_event) event:

```js
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card';
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export class MyComponent extends Component {

  onAuxClick(event) {
    if (event.button === 1) {
      // Middle mouse button has been clicked! Do what you will with it...
    }
  }
    
  render() {
    return (
      <Card onAuxClick={this.onAuxClick.bind(this)}>
      </Card>
    );
}
```

Comment: `onAuxClick={(e) => e.button === 1 && this.onWheelClick(...`

Answer (score 4):

You can add a `mouseDown` event and then detect the middle button click like:

```
handleMouseDown = (event) => {
   if(event.button === 1) {
      // do something on middle mouse button click
   }
}
```

You code might look like:

```
class App extends React.Component {
   constructor() {
     super();

     this.onMouseDown = this.onMouseDown.bind(this);
   }
   componentDidMount() {
       document.addEventListener('mousedown', this.onMouseDown);
   }
   componentWillUnmount() {
       document.removeEventListener('mousedown', this.onMouseDown);
   }
   onMouseDown(event) {
       if (event.button === 1) {
          // do something on middle mouse button click
       }
   }
   render() {
     // ...
   }
}
```

You can find more information on `MouseEvent.button` here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/button

Be careful. Using `mousedown` won't always get you the behavior you want. A "click" is both a `mousedown` and a `mouseup` where the `x` and `y` values haven't changed. Ideally, your solution would store the `x` and `y` values on a `mousedown` and when `mouseup` occurs, you would measure to make sure they're in the same spot.

Even better than `mousedown` would be `pointerdown`. This configures compatibility with "touch" and "pen" events as well as "mouse" events. I highly recommend this method if pointer events are compatible with your app's compatible browsers.

Comment: Instead of `event.which`, which isn't standardized, you should really be using `event.button` which is also part of React's proxied events like `onMouseDown`. On top of that, `mousedown` isn't the same as `click` because it doesn't wait for a `mouseup`.

Comment: There is now an onAuxClick event in modern browsers. You can handle the middle click there, and it also handles the context menu open in new tab. For some reason I can't submit this as an answer so hopefully this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

You can use React Synthetic event as described below

```
<div tabIndex={1} onMouseDown={event => { console.log(event)}}>
    Click me
</div>
```

Comment: downvoted. question is about middle click not mousedown.

Answer (score -3):

You can keep `onClick`. In React, you have access to `nativeEvent` property from where you can read which button was pressed:

```
const clickHandler = (evt) => {
  if (e.nativeEvent.button === 1) {
    ...
  }
}

return (
  <a onClick={clickHandler}>test</a>
)
```