# window.open with _blank opens two tabs in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

When this element is middle clicked:

```js
// Allow middle button click to open client in another tab.
$(document).on('mousedown', '.clientlist-edit', function (event) {
    if (event.which === 2) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        url = url.toLowerCase().replace('/addedit', '/clientindex');
        window.open(url, '_blank');

        return false;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="clientlist-edit" href="/Clients/Management/AddEdit/4ffac190-72d2-476a-b0be-a9d90097272a">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>&nbsp;<strong class="title">Client Name</strong>
</a>
```

This handler is called and when it gets to `window.open`, two tabs are opened. The first is the URL (variable `URL`)  which is desired. The second is the original href set on the anchor element which is undesired. I'm calling `preventDefault`. What am I missing?

**It is reproducible.** See the link below. Sometimes it is two middle clicks. It is a *middle click*. It only happens in *Firefox*.

https://jsfiddle.net/jsmunroe/eap1b6k7/3/

I'm using Firefox 68.0.2.

[image]

Comment: Blank is default, so you shouldn't even need to add that.  If you debug in the console, is that event getting hit twice?

Comment: Check your markup--`&nbsp;class="title">Client Name</strong>` has an incomplete tag and a closing tag with no opening tag.

Comment: I've tried your code in a fiddle and it only gets called once. My guess is that your attaching the event twice... somewhere else.

Comment: @JohnPete22, both tabs are opened when I step over `window.open`. The event is called once. I will repeat, this only happens in FireFox.

Comment: @JohnPete22, I took out the '_blank' and you are right it does still work, but this didn't fix the problem.

Comment: @VVV, I added a jsfiddle link that reproduced the problem. It only happens in FireFox. And only after you've ok'd popups.

Comment: Have you tried the Fiddle in private browsing with any add-ons disabled?

Comment: I don't use FireFox, I don't have any add-ons.

Comment: I posted this as a bug to FireFox. It apparently happens in Edge v44.17763.1.0 too.
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1576182

Comment: This question has been [discussed on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388722/what-is-wrong-with-my-question-about-firefox-opening-two-tabs-for-a-link).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess your goal here is to intercept the user trying to open a link in a new tab and instead open a *different* link in a new tab. If I'm correct, then you're going to need to adjust your strategy in a few key ways:

1. **Don't use `mousedown`**

   Click events are triggered by a mouse-down followed by a mouse-up event. That means that *normally* you have to press **and release** the button before any click-type thing happens, whether that's navigation (left-click), context menu (right-click) or open in new tab (middle-click). If you try to simulate this using mousedown, it's gonna feel *weird* - the action will happen too soon!

   Also, as you've now observed, it won't work correctly: the corresponding click event will still happen *after* your handler runs, because you're not cancelling the right event. What *does* your `preventDefault()` / `return false` accomplish? Well, try holding the middle button down and dragging: most browser will probably pan around the view as you move your mouse, but if you try this on your "Middle Click Me" element... Nothing happens. Yep, you've only succeeded in making your page slightly more annoying to scroll around on.
2. **DO use the `auxclick` event**.

   I'm guessing you went with `mousedown` in the first place because you observed that nothing fired for a middle click when you captured the `click` event. A few years ago, `click` would've worked fine - but now, `click` only fires for the *primary* mouse button. **This is a good thing!** Way too many people inadvertently blocked right- and middle-clicks by capturing `click`, when they only intended to capture left-clicks. Presumably if you're capturing `auxclick`, you know what you're doing and can be trusted to handle it properly. (so, y'know... Do be careful)

[The w3c actually has rather good documentation on all of this](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#event-type-click), so I'd be remiss if I didn't link to it and quote the relevant bits here:

> The click event should only be fired for the primary pointer button (i.e., when button value is 0, buttons value is 1). Secondary buttons (like the middle or right button on a standard mouse) MUST NOT fire click events. See auxclick for a corresponding event that is associated with the non-primary buttons.
>
> The click event MAY be preceded by the mousedown and mouseup events on the same element, disregarding changes between other node types (e.g., text nodes). Depending upon the environment configuration, the click event MAY be dispatched if one or more of the event types mouseover, mousemove, and mouseout occur between the press and release of the pointing device button. The click event MAY also be followed by the dblclick event.

Finally, here's your snippet with the changes above, for your review (you can't actually test it here, [since `window.open` is blocked in Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278491/how-can-i-embed-an-angular-ui-router-app-as-a-stackoverflow-snippet/278795#278795) - but you'll get an error indicating this and *not* see any tabs open; paste it into your fiddle for a real test):

```js
// Allow middle button click to open client in another tab.
$(document).on('auxclick', '.clientlist-edit', function (event) {
    if (event.which === 2) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        url = url.toLowerCase().replace('/addedit', '/clientindex');
        window.open(url, '_blank');

        return false;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="clientlist-edit" href="/Clients/Management/AddEdit/4ffac190-72d2-476a-b0be-a9d90097272a">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>&nbsp;<strong class="title">Client Name</strong>
</a>
```

Yep - the only change is `mousedown` -> `auxclick`! Enjoy...

### Further reading

- [Middle button click event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41110264/middle-button-click-event)
- [UI Events - event type click - W3C Editor's Draft](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#event-type-click)
- [Element: auxclick event on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/auxclick_event)