# Firefox and Chrome add target=_blank to asp.net linkbuttons

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, firefox, webforms, linkbutton

A few weeks ago we started to get complaints that links were not working on our asp.net web forms site for users on Firefox browsers. On investigation, we fou d that the anchor tag that was rendered had a target="_blank" attribute.
Recently, we started to notice the same on Chrome, has anyone observed similar and is there any way to turn this off?

Comment: Saw another thread where Firefox was opening anchors to new tabs ("_blank") two times.  But that's odd it's adding ```blank``` and not ```_blank```

Comment: Typo mate, I'll correct the question. Did you come across a solution in this other thread?

Comment: Not sure if it will help or not: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57579926/window-open-with-blank-opens-two-tabs-in-firefox/57599803#57599803

Comment: To nitpick a bit, you're saying the links don't work. Do they really not work, or is it just that the target is being mysteriously added but the links still work?

Comment: Can you change it to a Hyperlink button? It actually has a target property. (Leave default, I guess.) [Possible previous answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9255427/c-sharp-target-blank-in-a-linkbutton).