# How can I trigger onwheel event up and down effect in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I want to trigger a function or loop when onwheel scroll up or scroll down.
Please see my snippet.

```js
let demo = document.querySelector('#demo');
let c = 0;
window.onwheel = function() {
  c ++;
  demo.innerHTML = c;
}
```

```css
body{
height: 300vh;

}
h1{
position: fixed;
text-align: center;
width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="demo" > Hello World </h1>
```

I need when it will scroll up the number should be increment and 
when scroll down number should be decrements. but it's just increment the number, I need js clear solution. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795734/triggering-onclick-event-using-middle-click

Comment: You can use `addEventListener` for scroll events. Please check the documentation, you’ll find a complete example : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/scroll_event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
window.onwheel = function(event) {
  if (event.deltaY > 0) {
    // down
  } else {
    // up
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `wheel` event listener and get the direction with `event.deltaY` :

```js
let demo = document.querySelector('#demo');
let c = 0;

window.addEventListener('wheel', function(event) {
  if (event.deltaY < 0) {
    console.log('scrolling up');
    if (c == 0) { // no negative values
      demo.innerHTML = 0;
    } else {;
      c--;
      demo.innerHTML = c;
    }
  } else if (event.deltaY > 0) {
    console.log('scrolling down');
    //if (c != 0) {
    c++;
    demo.innerHTML = c;
    // }
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 300vh;
}

h1 {
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="demo"> Hello World </h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also just remember window.pageYOffset and check if you actually scrolled down (must be greater than remembered value)

```js
let demo = document.querySelector('#demo');
let c = 0;
let last_scroll= window.pageYOffset;
window.onwheel = function() {
  if(window.pageYOffset >= last_scroll && last_scroll != 0){
    c ++;
    demo.innerHTML = c;
  }
  last_scroll = window.pageYOffset;
}
```

```css
body{
height: 300vh;

}
h1{
position: fixed;
text-align: center;
width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="demo" > Hello World </h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var demoHeight = demo.offsetHeight; 
 demo.onscroll = function(){}
```