# How do I make jstree to select node only on left click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

Currently both left and right click select the node which interferes contextmenu as I use left clicks to go to other pages. How do I make `select_node.jstree` event know which mouse button is being clicked?

Comment: This might help you. Please have a look-
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944122/detect-left-mouse-button-press

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because I wanted the click event to be fired on left click I return false when the click event is fired for right click.

```
$("#orgTree").bind("select_node.jstree", function(event, data) {

            var evt =  window.event || event;
            var button = evt.which || evt.button;

            if( button != 1 && ( typeof button != "undefined")) return false; 

            ...

        });
```

Comment: @JakeOS this was answered in '14 not in '10 :) but I'm glad you found it helpful!

Answer (score 16):

You can also Use "select_node":false in the "contextmenu" section of your jstree settings to disable activating the node with the right click

see [jstree documentation for this](http://www.jstree.com/api/#/?f=$.jstree.defaults.contextmenu.select_node)

Comment: @silver @periklis I want the node to be selected on both button clicks. My question is how do I take different actions depending on which button triggered the `select_node.jstree` event.

Comment: @AlexanderSuraphel I'm not sure how to do this, why don't you post this as a new question?

Comment: @periklis that was the original intent of my question! But does making `"select_node":false` appear selected when right clicked?

Answer (score 0):

There is new [event](http://www.jqwidgets.com/community/topic/difference-between-itemclick-and-select-event-in-jqxtree/) `(itemClick)` available since version 4.0.0 released for handling left click only !

```
$('#jqxWidget').bind('itemClick', function (event) {
      //Other codes goes here.
}
```