# Is it possible to detect a mouse click on a page on every element?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to trigger a function if a user clicks anywhere on the page, even clicking on no element or link. Is it possible?

The extension runs only on youtube.com so I can't add every element on the page to the trigger and I assume that every page has different element's ids.

Comment: you can inject the code of the above question in the page so your problem will be solved.

Comment: Voting to reopen (..err, magically reopening by dupehammer), as duplicate is incorrect. It deals only with detecting whether a particular click event is a left mouse button (which isn't even asked by the OP!) and does not deal with the core problem of capturing the even anywhere on the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emmanouil Chountasis is correct, you can use the code at ["Detect left mouse button press"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944122/detect-left-mouse-button-press) to detect a left mouse click crossbrowser.

To the heart of your question, I think what you're looking for is Event Delegation. In jQuery,

```
// Select a wrapper for the events
$('body')
  // Whenever any element in the <body> is clicked
  .on('click', '*', function (evt) {
    // Emmanouil Chountasis's suggestion would be called right here
    if (isLeftClick(evt)) { 
      // ... do stuff
    }
  });
```

See http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 0):

Reed's answer works fine, but it triggers the action multiple times. I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14991189/4685471) that only works on left mouse triggers and executes *once* per click.

```
$("body").unbind().click(function() {
    //Do Stuff
});
```