# My tracking JavaScript is causing a right click to open the link - could someone help me spot the mistake in my code?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple line of code as below:

```
<a href="http://sub.domain.org" onmousedown="trackOutboundLink('http://sub.domain.org'); return false;" >
```

With JavaScript:

```
var trackOutboundLink = function(url) {
   ga('send', 'event', 'referral', 'click', url, {
     'transport': 'beacon',
     'hitCallback': function(){document.location = url;}
   });
}
```

I want to to track the clicks on the link, but I have `onmousedown` for the tracking for people who right click and open in new tab (I realize it won't be perfectly accurate, but that's ok).

The thing is, when you right click on the link, the page loads to the link now. I have removed the `onmousedown` command and the problem goes away, so I know it's that.

I though the `return false` is meant to prevent this? Thank you in advance for any help

Comment: Unanswerable without knowing what `trackOutboundLink` does. [mcve]

Comment: Remove `'hitCallback': function(){document.location = url;}`

Comment: Updated - I didn't think it should matter though

Comment: Don't I need hitCallback to define 'url'? When I remove it, the code breaks on testing

Comment: Yeah, you'll need to check if it was the right or left button and only set the location on left

Comment: Here's how to check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944122/detect-left-mouse-button-press

Comment: Than simply pass the `event` to your function `onmousedown="trackOutboundLink('http://sub.domain.org', event);`, check with an if and only update the location inside the if

Comment: Sorry bambam, I should have first experimented a bit more first - the code below in the Answers work for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Change JavaScript to:

```
var trackOutboundLink = function(url) {
   ga('send', 'event', 'referral', 'click', url, {
     'transport': 'beacon',
     function(){document.location = url;}
   });
}
```