# Javascript event to detect a link being followed

Tags: javascript, accessibility

Apart from the obvious `onclick` event handler, how can I detect if the user tabbed the link and hit enter or whatever other key/device that would make the link open?

Also, is it possible to detect a middle mouse button click (defaults to open in new tab)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pressing enter will produce an `onclick` event. You do not need any special code to handle the enter key

Edit: As for middle click you can look here: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html It is not so simple (thanks to IE)

Edit: If you use jQuery it is very simple: [How to distinguish between left and right mouse click with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206203/how-to-distinguish-left-mouse-click-and-right-with-jquery/2725963#2725963)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want a separate solution to catching specifically an ENTER key press on a link, you might be able to use `onkeyup` and check if the `event.keyCode` equals 13 (ENTER key).