# JQuery Right Click Problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, will-paginate, right-click

I have written the following JQuery which changes dynamically generated links on my Page (ruby on rails will_paginate) to GET requests which fetches JSON and refresh elements on my page. This works great in the case that they are left clicked. But in the event of a right click, the link GETS only JSON rendered information from my server and displays raw JSON in the a new window.

How can I revert back to the original link, in the event of Right Click?

```
// will_paginate + ajax 
// updates two divs: #pages and #pagelink
// see places#search controller; passes 4 parameters to the search action

$(function(){
  $(".pagination a").live("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  // Javascript Regular expression function; extracts page number from full url
  var extractPageNumber = function(s) {
    var r=/page=(\d+)/, m=(""+s).match(r);
    return (m) ? Number(m[1]) : undefined;
  };
  var pageregex = extractPageNumber($(this).attr('href'));
  $(".pagination").html("Page is loading...")
  $.get("/event", {  event: $("input[name=event]").val(), page: pageregex }, function(data) {
    $('#pagelink').html(data.page_link);
    $('#tweets').html(data.html);
    });
  return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: I see the evil `live` function.  Switch to `delegate`:`$(".pagination").delegate('a',"click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); . . .`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the answer to [How to distinguish between left and right mouse click with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206203/how-to-distinguish-between-left-and-right-mouse-click-with-jquery) on how to see a right click.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working. Does it not play nice with live?

Comment: I should note: This works once, only upon refresh. After I page through the links with left clicks THEN try the right click, it reverts back to JSON

Answer (score 0):

Check `event.which == 1`. This signifies left mouse button clicks.