# Disable mouse click when out of div

Tags: jquery

Hi i have a div of a form. i want that disable click event when mouse is out of the div. So i tried this but it is not working ot of div is still clickable. Any idea??

```
var flag = false;
$("#foo").live("mouseenter",function(){
    flag = true;
}).live("mouseleave",function(){
    flag = false;
})

$(document).click(function(){
    if(!flag)
         return false;
});
```

Comment: Why do you need to disable click outside the form? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: What do you mean by disable click outside of the div?

Comment: i show a div when click a link and when this div is shown i dont want to rest of document be clickable except of div..

Comment: @Sedat - Are you using any animation to show this div?

Comment: @Sedat - Check my another answer hope that helps you.

Comment: @SedatBaşar Is this "only" the left-click you want to disable? I think the `.click()` event handler may or may not trigger on other clicks (right, middle...), see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206203/how-to-distinguish-between-left-and-right-mouse-click-with-jquery

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot prevent the click event being fired from the whole document. You can do it per element basis. You can probably block the whole screen using a absolute positioned transparent(low opacity) div and hide it again once the div is visible.

```
var $body = $(document.body);
var $div = $("<div id='dummyDiv'/>").hide().appendTo($body);
$div.css({position:"absolute", height: $body.height(), width: $body.width(), background: "#000", opacity: 0.5}).show(100);

//to hide it
$("#dummyDiv").hide(100);
```

Comment: You can prevent the click event being fired from the whole document: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8596014/931358

Comment: +1 for simplicity. Adding an overlay makes the problem of click event handling irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#foo").live("mouseenter",function(){
    $(document).bind('click', onDocumentClick);
}).live("mouseleave",function(){
    $(document.unbind('click');
});

function onDocumentClick(e){

};
```

I think you want the click on `#foo` instead of `document`, if so you can simply do this:

```
$('#foo').click(function(){

});
```

Since you have to be rolled over an element to click on it this will work fine.

Comment: i wrote return false and e.preventDefault() in onDocumentClick func but both didnt worked..

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

istead of using return false, use `e.preventDefault`
http://css-tricks.com/6809-return-false-and-prevent-default/

Comment: @locrizak - they do *not* do the same thing, not at all.  One prevents the default action, one stops the event dead in it's tracks, stopping propagation as well.  Saying they're the same is entirely incorrect.