# How to completely DISABLE any MOUSE CLICK

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, mouseevent

After the user clicks on...."log in" button, and other events, I made a loading script -to let users know they have to wait (Until ajax replies back).

**How can I DISABLE any MOUSE CLICKS (right click, left click, double click, middle click, x click)**, on `div id="doc"`?

I want to add that code to `loading.js`

**HTML**

```
<html>
...
<body>
<div id="doc">
   <div id="content">
   ...
   <input type="button" value="Login" id="login" />
   ...
   </div id="content">
</div id="doc">
</body>
</html>
```

**loading.js**

```
function load_bar(x)
{
    if (x==0)
    {
    $(document.body).css( {"cursor": "default"} );
    $("body").css( {"cursor": "default"} );
    $("#loading").css("visibility", "hidden"); //modal window
//  $("#doc").....ENABLE all clicks (left/right/etc)
    }

    else if (x==1)
    {
    $(document.body).css( {"cursor": "wait"} );
    $("body").css( {"cursor": "wait"} );
    $("#loading").css( {"visibility": "visible"} ); //modal window
//  $("#doc").....DISABLE all clicks (left/right/etc)
    }

    else
    {
    return alert("Wrong argument!");
    }
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
//AJAX
$("#login").click(function()
{
    load_bar(1); //DISABLE clicks and show load_bar
    $(":input").attr("disabled", true);


$.post( 
    ...
    function(data)
    {
    ...
    load_bar(0); //ENABLE clicks and hide load_bar
    ...
    } //END: if:else
}); //END:$.post
    ...
}); //END:ajax
}); //END:jQuery
```

Comment: @alonisser I am using BOTH charles-ma and minitech solutions. Unfortunately I this website won't allow 2-votes >_<

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can overlay a big, semi-transparent `<div>` that takes all the clicks. Just append a new `<div>` to `<body>` with this style:

```css
.overlay {
    background-color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.7);
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

Comment: how can I add `loading.jpg` ( `$("#loading")` )at the very center of this div (`.overlay`) -Center of the screen?

Comment: @Omar: `background-image: url('loading.jpg'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center center;` would be one way. Another would be to add `text-align: center;` on `.overlay`, then add a new image (`#loading`) in `.overlay` with the style `margin-top: 50%; position: relative; top: -(half-image's-height)px`.

Comment: give `loading.jpg` a top and left equal to `parent.height()/2-loading.height()/2` and `parent.width()/2-loading.width()/2` respectively

Comment: @minitech Is there any difference between `background-position: center center;` and `text-align: center...`?

Comment: @Omar: I think the latter is a bit more compatible, but it will degrade gracefully all the same. `background-*` is a little cleaner in syntax.

Comment: @minitech I hope it's not too late. I tried this css on Firefox with no problems. However, I also need to make it compatible with IE. I tried several ways with no success.

Comment: @minitech This fiddle works fine on Firefox. With the exception that it does not center's properly. However, it does not work on IE8: http://jsfiddle.net/f7xFy/3/

Comment: @minitech I am not sure what I am doing wrong. The fiddle works just fine on IE, but not when I load the very same code on my client's host [http://tiny.cc/7brtd](http://tiny.cc/7brtd)

Comment: @Omar: You're in quirks mode. Add a `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

Comment: @minitech Great! Now to the next problem >_< Why is not centered? Right now is leaning tooooo much to the bottom

Comment: @Omar: Can you update your live web example to add that, please?

Comment: @minitech You mean this link: http://tiny.cc/7brtd? I updated it already (Added `<!DOCTYPE...>`)

Comment: @Omar: No, the thing that isn't centering.

Comment: @minitech ???...The div that is not centered is `<div id=loading"...` but I am not sure what you want me to update there...

Comment: @minitech It auto-aligns with the window's resizing changes too...wicked!!! Here is the final Fiddle (I added some persona customization) http://jsfiddle.net/jJ85P/

Comment: @minitech the div won't take a white border, but I can compromise =)   ...`id="stretch'` on your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/f7xFy/6/, or `id=loading_box` on my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jJ85P/

Comment: @minitech why adding the jQuery from "Charles Ma"'s answer when your original answer works without it (hence making the code simpler). see http://jsbin.com/qixiwuqozive/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: @AdrienBe: I just updated the fiddle Omar linked above. I don’t really remember what this whole thing is about anymore…

Comment: how can we make it work for IE8 as it doesnot take alpha property of background color in rgba ?

Comment: @tarun_telang: Set it to an opaque background colour and use the `opacity` property.

Comment: @minitech - opactity attribute is also not supported in IE 8.

Comment: for IE 8 the following CSS code needs to be used. {filter: alpha(opacity=80); opacity: 0.8}

Answer (score 79):

You can add a simple css3 rule in the body or in specific div, use `pointer-events: none;` property.

Comment: this solution is awesome, so easy

Comment: Also disables all cursor events, like changing the pointer. Seems to be only recommended for SVG applications.

Comment: Genius. 
I've been searching for a solution couple of hours - this one is the most practical and easy by far.

Answer (score 21):

To disable all mouse click

```
var event = $(document).click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    return false;
});

// disable right click
$(document).bind('contextmenu', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    return false;
});
```

to enable it again:

```
$(document).unbind('click');
$(document).unbind('contextmenu');
```

Comment: I did not know you could disable clicks on the whole document! I guess I do not need `<div id="doc">` after all =)

Comment: That won't disable middle-clicks. Also, an event handler set at the document level will be called _after_ the event bubbles up from the actual elements. (You're calling `stopPropagation()` after it has already propagated to the top.) http://jsfiddle.net/WWx9B/

Comment: You're right, JS handlers bound to elements below document will still fire, but it does stop html clickable events like link navigation and form submission. it also doesn't disable middle click, and I don't know a cross browser way to disable it. But the OP can probably achieve what he wants using a mix of my approach and a css overlay described by @minitec

Comment: @charles-ma I guess you are right! A mixed approach is a better choice.

Comment: @charles-ma Even with this code, it is still clicking on IE8: http://jsfiddle.net/f7xFy/3/

Comment: hm...try returning false from those functions. I don't have IE8 to test right now

Comment: ??? I am a beginner...what do you mean by returning false? isn't it already returning false...`e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    return false;`?

Comment: @Omar see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5302903/jquery-event-stopimmediatepropagation-vs-return-false

Comment: @CharlesMa although I like your solution (a jQuery approach), why would you use both your solution & the one of "minitec", when just using the one from "minitec" seems to work just fine for all clicks (right, left, middle...). see http://jsbin.com/nuzezayiliko/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: ooops, there was a small mistake in the live example I provided. See the correct one http://jsbin.com/picewamajufo/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined

Answer (score 8):

something like:

```
    $('#doc').click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault()
       e.stopImmediatePropagation() //charles ma is right about that, but stopPropagation isn't also needed
});
```

should do the job
you could also bind more mouse events with replacing for:
**edit**:
add this in the feezing part

```
    $('#doc').bind('click mousedown dblclick',function(e){
       e.preventDefault()
       e.stopImmediatePropagation()
});
```

and this in the unfreezing:

```
  $('#doc').unbind();
```

Comment: I am a beginner, could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to freeze the UI would be to make the AJAX call synchronous.

Usually synchronous AJAX calls defeat the purpose of using AJAX because it freezes the UI, but if you *want* to prevent the user from interacting with the UI, then do it.

Comment: +1 Good idea :) Although, if the user presses a bunch of keys in frustration, won't they all come back after it's done?

Comment: @gilly3 I have noooo idea what you are talking about :,(  It sounds gibberish to me (too advanced)