# Web App: How to disable mouse & keyboard?

Tags: web-applications, keyboard, mouse

A client of mine asked me if it was possible through a webapp to completely disable both client's keyboard & mouse. Ideally in jQuery or Html5.

I saw [a way to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595909/how-to-completley-disable-any-mouse-click) but only on the web page not the whole keyboard.

Comment: Your client wants to render his user's computer inoperable? Really?

Comment: He's a teacher and he wants his students not to go on facebook when he talks...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).bind("keypress", function (e) {
        // Prevent any key
        return false;
    });

    $(document).bind("click", function(e) {
        // Prevent clicks
        return false;
    });
});
```

It should work, but not sure if it's cross browser.

Added the `click` handler also.

Comment: Hello! This is a good way to block keyboard inside the web-page. But is there a way to completely block keyboard & mouse even out of the browser?

Comment: Through a browser? No.  You can perhaps create a desktop application that facilitates this, but maybe a better option is to unplug the keyboard/mouse and use remote access to control the PC if required.

Can you give more information on the context of this?

Comment: OK. Thank you for your answer. Here is the situation. The teacher wants through my webapp to block the student's keyboards connected just clicking on a button. Is that possible?

Comment: This is not possible through the browser.  You can perhaps write a desktop application to achieve this.

Comment: @ValentinVrinceanu Without understanding your application of this technique it is difficult to judge what is/isnt working.  Can you open a new question with the details of your approach and list any problems you are experiencing.

Comment: i just tried on a webpage to stop all the keyboard and mouse actions using your code.

Answer (score 0):

Using [AutoIt3](http://autoitscript.com), for example, it's very simple. But from webapps, block mouse and keyboard for all the OS' environment isn't possible.

In AutoIt3, here's an example:

```
; By default, AU3 add an tray icon for closing the app. No longer:
#NoTrayIcon
; For >=Vista, windows will require administrator privilleges to do that
#RequireAdmin
; Now...
BlockInput(1) ; mouse and keyboard are both lockeds!
While 1
   Sleep(100) ; loop for pause script
WEnd
```

Just compile that and run.