# prevent all MouseClick event until page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a situation in which i have to prevent all **MouseClick** events until the page loads.

i have 1 javascript function defined on page load like

```
onload="init();"
```

Now in function init(), we are showing tree and select a particular node of it.

```
function init() {
        ExpandAncestors(node);
        ExpandNode(node);
        setTimeout("treeScrollToView()", 1000);
}
```

Now i want to prevent all the mouse click event on tree/page until whole tree is not fully shown.

I have searched through some of the posts related to my question but that uses **event.preventDefault()** but i dont have **Event** object here.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: **[THIS LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8595953/2065039)** might be helpful too..

Answer (score 9):

You can use:

**CSS**

```
body {
  pointer-events:none;
}
```

**and then on page load reactivate them**

```
$(document).ready(() => {
  $('body').css('pointer-events', 'all') //activate all pointer-events on body
})
```

**Explanation**

`pointer-events:none;` *blocks* all mouse interaction with the elements it's applied to - Since the `body` is usually the parent of all the elements in your page, it would case them not to react to any mouse interaction at all.

Keep in mind that *all* mouse interaction would be blocked this way, not only mouse clicks but mouse hover, mouse up's etc etc..

Comment: This has [pretty terrible support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events) for a simple task

Comment: This would apply for entire body. He want it for tree only.

Comment: @vijay, so.. he can use `body *` - on the other hand @vihan1086 makes a solid point - didn't know that

Comment: Also `pointer-events` doesn't prevent a right-click. Not sure if that's anything important though

Comment: It doesn't allow a right-click *on the DOM* - browser right clicks are a different story

Answer (score 4):

I think the basic need is to prevent user from clicking the tree area. I would prefer to display an overlay div rather than playing with the tree mouse click events.

You can show a loading overlay on the tree part until it is loaded. once done, you can hide the loading and show your original tree.

Ref: [How to completely DISABLE any MOUSE CLICK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595909/how-to-completley-disable-any-mouse-click/8595953#8595953)

Comment: not that it would make any noticeable difference - but this would be the most *performant* way of doing this - add some code for this

Comment: I have added the reference link. Re-usability is the best policy :)

Comment: This is the best way to do it... show transparent overlay while page loads... Most efficient and reliable way to sort click issues

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript Only

You can have an event listener along with a boolean. `onclick` disables a click. `oncontextmenu` disables right clicks.

```
(function(){window.onload = function () {

    var allowClicks = false;

    document.onclick = function (e) {  !allowClicks&&e.preventDefault();  }
    document.oncontextmenu = function (e) {  !allowClicks&&e.preventDefault();  }
    document.getElementById('myElement').onload = function () { allowClicks = true; }

}());
```

`myElement` is your element which you can replace with whatever

---

#### Use this with one element

If you want to disable mouse clicks for just *one* element, do:

```
(function(){window.onload = function () {

    var allowClicks = false,
        elem = document.getElementById('myElement');

    elem.onclick = function (e) {  !allowClicks&&e.preventDefault();  }
    elem.oncontextmenu = function (e) {  !allowClicks&&e.preventDefault();  }
    elem.onload = function () { allowClicks = true; }

}());
```

---

Comment: It may be better to `.addEventListener` rather than `.onclick`

Comment: @PaulS. I think `.onload` has slightly better support though

Comment: @Vijay I hate globals to! I'm not sure how OP is going to use this so I'll add another version. I group all my globals into a single global object, `globals`

Comment: don't you think it should be `if (!window.globals || !window.globals.allowclicks)` ??

Comment: @Vijay Yup, I just noticed that which I fixed. I also put code in a self-executing function to avoid globals :)

Answer (score 0):

`onload="init();"` here you can have `event` object.

pass event as argument.

`onload="init(event);"`

now you can use that in `init()` function.

Comment: That will give you an event but you are running`e.preventDefault()` on the window.onload

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing [$.holdReady()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.holdReady)

```js
$.holdReady(true);

$(window).off("click");

$("*").each(function(i, el) {
  this.onclick = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});

 function init() {
  $("div").on("click", function() {
    alert($.now())
  })
}

setTimeout(function() {
  $.holdReady(false);
}, 7000)

$(function() {
    init()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<body>
<div>click</div>
  <a href="javascript:alert(new Date())">click</a>
</body>
```