# Disable click event on all controls using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to use *pure javascript* (due to application architechture) to disable click event on html page.

I tried

```
document.body.addEventListener("click", function (evt) { evt.preventDefault(); });
```

but it still opens my select.

I used `select` just as an example, I want to do it for every control.

Here is [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k1pujcz3/8/)

**Update**
Can't use `pointer-events:none;` because I am using it inside `WPF` application and sadly it uses frustrating browser known as `IE`.

Answer (score 28):

You can easily achieve this by CSS

```
<select style="pointer-events:none;"> 
   <option>a</option>
   <option>b</option> 
<select>
```

Comment: I have to use IE which doesn't support it. Thanks for answer. +1 because it is helpful in other scenarios

Comment: @Imad, please check the updated answer.

Answer (score 16):

Add simple css,
`pointer-events: none`, if you give it to body element, evety click gets disabled.

```html
<html>
<body  style="pointer-events: none">
<select> 
  <option>a</option>
  <option>b</option> 
</select>
 </body>
  </html>
```

**Please run the code snippet**

```
 <select style="pointer-events: none"> 
  <option>a</option>
  <option>b</option> 
</select>
```

[Here is the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k1pujcz3/3/)

**EDIT FOR IE:**

```js
document.addEventListener("click",handler,true);

function handler(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
}

function cancelDropDown(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

var showMenu = document.getElementsByClassName("selectElement");

// ...

for ( var i = 0; i < showMenu.length; ++i ) {
    showMenu[i].addEventListener("mousedown", cancelDropDown, false);
}
```

```html
<select class="selectElement"> 
  <option>a</option>
  <option>b</option> 
</select>
<select class="selectElement"> 
  <option>c</option>
  <option>d</option> 
</select>
<select class="selectElement"> 
  <option>e</option>
  <option>f</option> 
</select>
<a onclick="alert('a')">asd</a>
```

[Fiddle 2](https://jsfiddle.net/k1pujcz3/9/)

Comment: Oh, sorry but I forgot to mention it should work in IE as WPF browser using IE only. +1 for the answer thogh.

Comment: problem with ID is I will have to know ID of every element. As I mentioned in question, I have to do it for all elements.

Comment: The click event listener somehow doesn't work only for select, what you can  do is take the same class fot all the select tags, and perform the `getelementsbyclassName` on it.

Answer (score 0):

> Neither the onSelect() nor onClick() events are supported by the  tag. The former refers to selecting text (i.e. by clicking + dragging across a text field) so can only be used with the  and  tags. The onClick() event can be used with  tags - however, you probably are looking for functionality where it would be best to use the onChange() event, not onClick().

LINK: [How to use onClick() or onSelect() on option tag in a JSP page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487263/how-to-use-onclick-or-onselect-on-option-tag-in-a-jsp-page)

I think you much try **pointer-events: none** with **style** attribute

You can try more answer for this :)
[How to completely DISABLE any MOUSE CLICK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595909/how-to-completley-disable-any-mouse-click)

I think you much insert 1 overlay element and bring it to front select element :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<select style="pointer-events: none" id="select" onchange="handleSelect()"> 
  <option value="01">a</option>
  <option>b</option> 
  </select>
```

and use the following javascript

```
function handleSelect() {
    if (this.value == '01') {
      document.getElementById('select').disabled = true;
     } else {
     document.getElementById('select').disabled = false;
            }
                        }
```

Comment: I don't even want to show that option list. complete disable.