# How to block user from accessing other tabs in Shiny unless the user clicks a button?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

My question is similar to [Shiny how to block the user from accessing a tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69766514/shiny-how-to-block-the-user-from-accessing-a-tab)

But what I need here is:
-Block other tabs unless the user clicks on a submit button
-Automatically move to the other tab once that submit button is clicked. Here is an example code

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(navbarPage(
  "",
  tabPanel(
    h1("Tab1"), 
    value = "nav1",
    mainPanel(
      br(),
      h2("The user must press this button to access the other tab."),
      br(),
      shiny::actionButton('button', 'press the button', onclick = "$(tab).removeClass('disabled')")
    )
  ),
  tabPanel(
    h1("Tab2"),
    value = "nav2",
    uiOutput("tab2contents")
  ),
  tags$script(
    '
    var tab = $(\'a[data-value="nav2"]\').parent().addClass("disabled");
    $(function(){
      $(tab.parent()).on("click", "li.disabled", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
      });
    });
    '
  )
))    

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

})

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

In the above code, the 2nd tab is blocked unless the button is clicked, but how can I update this further so that once the button is clicked the user is automatically taken to the 2nd tab?

Comment: maybe `shiny::updateTabItems` , called from an `observeEvent` for the submit button?

Comment: I tried this with the following code but it is not working :(
```
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {
observeEvent(input$button,{
     updateTabItems(session=session,"tabs", selected = "Tab2")
    })
})
```

Comment: "Not working" isn't very specific!  Was the error something like "Object 'session' not found"?  if so, that's probably because you didn't add `session` to your sewrver function.

Comment: I never used `navbarPage`. Maybe give `shinydashboard` a try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you put the `tabPanel` in a `navbarPage` you have to use `updateNavbarPage`. And you need to give the `navbarPage` an `id`.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(navbarPage(
  "", id = "mainpage",
  tabPanel(
    h1("Tab1"), 
    value = "nav1",
    mainPanel(
      br(),
      h2("The user must press this button to access the other tab."),
      br(),
      shiny::actionButton('button', 'press the button', onclick = "$(tab).removeClass('disabled')")
    )
  ),
  tabPanel(
    h1("Tab2"),
    value = "nav2",
    uiOutput("tab2contents")
  ),
  tags$script(
    '
    var tab = $(\'a[data-value="nav2"]\').parent().addClass("disabled");
    $(function(){
      $(tab.parent()).on("click", "li.disabled", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
      });
    });
    '
  )
))    

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$button,
               {
                 updateNavbarPage(inputId = "mainpage", selected = "nav2")
               }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
})

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```