# How do I disable all interactive events (click/touch/scroll) within the page in Angular2?

Tags: angular, ionic2

I want to try an `interaction lock` in the current page that disables all interactive events like

1. `Tap and Click Events`
2. `Pan, press and Swipe Events`
3. `Page Scroll`

I'm thinking of a button click event which would simply set a boolean var **`disableTouch`** to true or false. I could implement an if statement in all of the functions that involve the events. However, that's a lot of work and doesn't seem to be the best approach.

```
updateData()
{
  if (!disableTouch) {
    // run the function
  }
}
```

Also, this method isn't applicable for disabling page scroll. How do I achieve this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595909/how-to-completley-disable-any-mouse-click

Comment: @anonym did you figure out the answer to this question

Answer (score 1):

You could make a custom directive that manages all interactions to an element. Then team the directive up with a service to change whether you are able to use it.

*interaction.directive.ts*

```
import { Directive, HostListener, EventEmitter, Output} from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
    selector: "[interaction]"
})
export class CursorDirective {

    @Output() public emitInUse = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

    constructor(private interactionService: InteractionService) { }

    @HostListener("click")
    public onMouseClick() {

        if(this.interactionService.inUse) {

            this.emitInUse.emit(this.interactionService.inUse);
        }
    }
}
```

*interaction.service.ts*

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

@Injectable() 
export class InteractionService { 

    public inUse: boolean;

    public changeInteractionState() {

        if (this.inUse) {

            this.inUse = false;
        } else {

            this.inUse = true;
        }
    }

}
```