# I am having sketch.js with particles but the particles are over my navbar so the links are not clickable

Tags: javascript, html, navbar, sketch.js

I am using particles.js by `sketch.js`

It is a nice effect and I want to use it but when I am doing so it is placed over my website's navbar and thus the links are not clickable

I tried `Z-INDEX : 99999;`, but it still "overlaps my nabvar"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand you have placed your `sketch.js` canvas on top of your navbar, thus the nav is not clickable?

Try putting `pointer-events: none;` on the `sketch.js` canvas or its immediate container. Setting this property to none means that the element will "pass through" all of the mouse events.

Comment: the problem is till not solved because when  I set *pointer-events:none;* the [sketch.js](http://soulwire.github.io/sketch.js/examples/particles.html) effect is not performed pls help

Comment: my effect is mouse move parallax so I tried it but then no effects takes place

Comment: okay then you can try preventing the click events on your `sketch.js` canvas (or its container) - https://stackoverflow.com/a/8596014/1777688