# jQuery: Detect Mouse Click and Open Target in New Tab

Tags: jquery

I'm currently designing a simple forum application.  It's mostly powered by jQuery/AJAX and loads everything on the same page; however, I know that sometimes users want to open several topics at once to look at them in new tabs when browsing a forum.

My solution to this was to detect when the middle mouse button is clicked and the left mouse button is clicked, and doing different actions then.  I want to load the target with AJAX in the window when the left-mouse button is clicked, otherwise load it in a new tab.

My only problem is I don't know of a way to open a target location in a new tab with jQuery.  Obviously opening new tabs at will isn't allowed, but is there a way to assign this type of behavior to a user-generated action?

Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Please take look on sample code. It may help

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    jQuery(function($){
        $('a').mousedown(function(event) {
            switch (event.which) {
                case 1:
                    //alert('Left mouse button pressed');
                    $(this).attr('target','_self');
                    break;
                case 2:
                    //alert('Middle mouse button pressed');
                    $(this).attr('target','_blank');
                    break;
                case 3:
                    //alert('Right mouse button pressed');
                    $(this).attr('target','_blank');
                    break;
                default:
                    //alert('You have a strange mouse');
                    $(this).attr('target','_self"');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: When clicking on the link, would it change the target attribute before the action is executed?

Comment: Yes, I will change attribute before action.

Comment: i want when user click on link or open it a new tab .the link hiding but by these ways it possible only on IE...what can i do?

Comment: how bout right click then you choose to open in new window?

Answer (score 10):

```
<a href="some url" target="_newtab">content of the anchor</a>
```

In javascript you can use

```
$('#element').mousedown(function(event) {
      if(event.which == 3) { // right click
          window.open('page.html','_newtab');
      }
})
```

Comment: Ah I see, didn't know I could set the target attribute on window.open.  Will give this a try.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You need to also consider that ctrl-click and cmd-click are used to open new tabs (in windows/linux and mac respectively. Therefore, this would be a more complete solution:

```
jQuery.isClickEventRequestingNewTab = function(clickEvent) {
    return clickEvent.metaKey || clickEvent.ctrlKey || clickEvent.which === 2;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    $('#element').mousedown(function(event) {
          if(event.which == 3) { // right click
              window.open("newlocation.html","");
          }
    });
```

See it live http://jsfiddle.net/8CHTm/1/

Comment: @Philip I have added a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

The default action of the middle mouse button is to open in a new tab.

You could set the hyperlinks target attribute to _blank to open a new tab.

```
<a href="#link" target="_blank">Link</a>
```

You can also refer to this question [How to distinguish between left and right mouse click with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206203/how-to-distinguish-between-left-and-right-mouse-click-with-jquery)

Comment: I need to edit my question and make it more clear.  I'm looking to load the target with AJAX on left-click, and open in a new tab on middle-mouse click.

Answer (score -1):

Please try "_newTab" instead of "_blank"

window.open( URL , "_newtab");