# Stop ctrl + click from returning 404 for modals in ruby/rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, http-status-code-404

Ruby/Rails Jquery

Forcing a link to open in a new tab by pressing ctrl + click returns a 404 page when the response is not HTML. I would like to be able to throw an alert that says "This link is not available in a new tab."

What is the best way to accomplish this globally? I have already updated the high-use cases where the action is controlled by a JQuery 'on click' event, but I am looking for a more robust solution.

Example:
HTML:

```
 <a href="http://some_link/some_action">some link</a>
```

CONTROLLER:

```
 def some_action
   ...
   respond_to do |format|
     format.js
   end
 end
```

Comment: You're going to need to give at least a little bit of code here for context. Opening in a new window shouldn't cause an automatic 404 so long as your link isn't pure JavaScript.

Comment: Any response that is returned from the controller that is not HTML. For example JS or JSON. Im not sure what kind of code you are looking for?
Its a link and the controller returns JS.

Comment: I have updated my question.

Comment: You may need to put in some sort of useful HTML version to capture the case where someone opens it in a new tab. Your controller is JavaScript only.

Comment: I was thinking that could be an option as well, unfortunately, some of those links are bootstrap modals and it would lose some of the look and feel of a regular application.

Comment: Unless you can prevent clicking and opening in a new tag, something that can be done by having no link but include a `click()` handler, you absolutely must produce something HTML-wise when it's clicked even if it's a "how did you get here" page.

Comment: I'm going to tinker with adding an instance variable to the controller that records all the params, overload the respond_to block with a generic index page and have some JS fire that reloads the content. Kinda hacky but I want that application "look and feel".

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple of options but what I would suggest is using something like this:

```js
$('.js-non-tabbable-link').on('click', function(event) {
  if (event.metaKey || event.ctrlKey){
    console.log("NOPE");
    event.preventDefault();
  } 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class='js-non-tabbable-link'>Click Me</a>
```

Comment: This is probably the best answer. Unless anyone knows of a way to detect a control click from the controller action.

Comment: I will accept this answer if no one else comes up with anything by tomorrow.

Comment: I don't know that anything is injected into the HTTP Headers when you control click but you could always confirm with some debugging.

Comment: @tadman, no it doesn't but I think this post addresses that (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7554507/jquery-detect-mouse-click-and-open-target-in-new-tab)