# Is it possible to capture "Open in New Tab" clicked event of context menu using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, contextmenu, right-click

I know I can use capture the Right Click event by using jQuery's "[contextmenu](https://api.jquery.com/contextmenu/)" but my question is, how can I capture the event after the context menu appears i.e. When the user clicks on "Open Link in New Tab" action.

Any help?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: You refer this post here: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850058/is-it-possible-to-detect-if-a-user-has-opened-a-link-in-a-new-tab

Comment: I referred to the link that you provided and it seems they are dealing with the page after it has been opened in another tab. Like looking at it's history on the page load event. What I need to do is rather capture the event on the same page before opening the new page.

Comment: I don’t think that is possible at all, at least not from JS running in a website context. This smells very [X/Y problem-y](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/286047) - can you please describe what actual problem you are trying to solve with this?

Comment: My situation is that I have a search result page which is in an ASPX application. When the user clicks on a particular link (which appears upon hovering) in the result row from the search result, I need to turn that row into a different color to identify that it has been viewed. A regular click I can handle no problem. However when the user opens this link by using "Open Link In New Tab" context menu, I don't know if I can capture this click. Thanks for introducing me to the X/Y problem though.

Answer (score 1):

Regrettably, directly capturing the event triggered by the browser's context menu when selecting "Open Link in New Tab" through JavaScript is not feasible. The context menu, along with its actions, including "Open Link in New Tab," is an integral part of the browser's user interface, and it remains inaccessible and uncontrollable through standard web APIs for security considerations.

Browsers are designed to prevent web pages from tampering with or capturing sensitive user interactions like opening links in new tabs. This intentional design aims to safeguard users from potential malicious activities.

If your objective is to execute specific actions when a link is opened in a new tab, you might want to explore alternative approaches. For instance, adding custom click handlers to your links can help capture click events, but it won't provide information about whether the user opted to open the link in a new tab from the context menu.

It's crucial to bear in mind that attempting to manipulate or interfere with browser-level interactions without explicit user consent can result in a suboptimal user experience and may be perceived as intrusive. Respecting user privacy and adhering to browser security features is paramount.

Answer (score -3):

I found this solution

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
jQuery(function($){
    $('a').mousedown(function(event) {
        switch (event.which) {
            case 1:
                //alert('Left mouse button pressed');
                $(this).attr('target','_self');
                break;
            case 2:
                //alert('Middle mouse button pressed');
                $(this).attr('target','_blank');
                break;
            case 3:
                //alert('Right mouse button pressed');
                $(this).attr('target','_blank');
                break;
            default:
                //alert('You have a strange mouse');
                $(this).attr('target','_self"');
        }
    });
});
```

Here [jQuery: Detect Mouse Click and Open Target in New Tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7554507/jquery-detect-mouse-click-and-open-target-in-new-tab)

Comment: Your solution allows me to capture the different mouse clicks but it does not help with capturing the event click on the Context Menu that appears after right click.

Comment: You need to use library to handler your context menu. Try to use this 
https://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/demo.html

Comment: Thanks for the link Ryuk but this is creating a custom context menu for the user that disables the browser's default right click interaction. I was looking for something to capture the default interaction provided by the browser. :)