# How do I distinguish left/right/double click in the handler if $.live('click')?

Tags: jquery, live

```
....live('click', function(){
   /*How do I distinguish left/right/double click*/
});
```

It seems `event.button` can be used to distinguish left and right click, but how to distinguish double click?

And I don't know if `event.button` is supported by all major browsers..

Comment: As far as I know, you must use `dblclick` handler for that, not `click`...

Comment: See this for possible answer to your question: [How to distinguish between left and right mouse click with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206203/how-to-distinguish-between-left-and-right-mouse-click-with-jquery)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well there is a separate event handler for doubleclick.. The event is [dblclick](http://api.jquery.com/dblclick/)

Comment: But I need to use it with `live` to bind future elements.

Comment: The `dblclick` handler will also fire the `click` handler, at least in certain operating systems and/or browsers. It is "officially" inadvisable to use both. I suppose one could apply a time delay to the contents of the `click` handler and then test if the `dblclick` event was fired.

Comment: What about left/right click? Is there a more elegant solution than @Prasanth's ?

Comment: @JeRog: the `click` handler only detects a mouse click, not which button. That's as elegant as it gets.

Answer (score 4):

This seems to solve the left and right click issue:

```
$("#element").live('click', function(e) {
    if( e.button == 0 ) {
        // Left mouse button was clicked (non-IE)
    }
});
```

For IE

```
$("#element").live('click', function(e) {
    if( e.button == 1 ) {
        // Left mouse button was clicked (IE only)
    }
});
```

See the link for more details

[jQuery live click binds](http://abeautifulsite.net/blog/2009/05/jquery-live-click-binds-both-the-left-and-right-mouse-buttons/)