# How to activate jquery right click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to distinguish between left and right mouse click with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206203/how-to-distinguish-between-left-and-right-mouse-click-with-jquery)

On right click I want to go to a different page..using jquery, how to do that? any idea?

thanks-

Comment: Do you want to annoy your users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

HTML

```
<a id="test" href=#">Click me</a>
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#test").mousedown(function(e) {
        switch (e.which) {
            case 1:
                alert("Left click... boring!");
                break;
            case 3:
                alert("Right-click... off to new page...");
                window.top.location = "http://www.google.com/";
                break;
        }
    })
});
```

JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gHkZs/)