# jQuery Detect continual mousedown

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to detect continual mousedown? In other words, I want a function to continue to run while the left mouse button is being pressed. Here is an example of what im trying to do. I have a button that controls the scrollLeft position. It increments by 20 on every click, but I want it to continue incrementation while the mouse button is left pressed and stop onmouseup.

Similar to how the arrows on a scroll bar work when you leave the mouse button pressed

```
    var wrapperDiv = $("#wrapper-div");
    var scrollWidth = 0;

    $("#right-button").click(function() {
      if(scrollWidth < wrapperDiv[0].scrollWidth) {
        scrollWidth = scrollWidth+20;
        wrapperDiv.scrollLeft(scrollWidth);
      }

});
```

Comment: if you having a problem in left, right and center mouse click detection have a look this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206203/how-to-distinguish-between-left-and-right-mouse-click-with-jquery).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use a `click` handler. Use two separate handlers, one for [`mousedown`](http://api.jquery.com/mousedown/) and one for [`mouseup`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseup/).

```
var $wrapper = $('#wrapper');

function startScrolling()
{
    // contintually increase scroll position
    $wrapper.animate({scrollLeft: '+=20'}, startScrolling);
}

function stopScrolling()
{
    // stop increasing scroll position
    $wrapper.stop();
}

$('#right-button').mousedown(startScrolling).mouseup(stopScrolling);
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/dkWGy/

Comment: This works only on the first click, but does not continue to increment. I need it to continue incrementation while the button is left pressed down. Similar to how the arrows on a scroll bar work when you leave the mouse button pressed

Comment: Sorry for the sloppiness - I fixed all the brokenness and added a working demo.

Answer (score 0):

How about using [mouseup](http://api.jquery.com/mouseup/) and [mousedown](http://api.jquery.com/mousedown/)?

Answer (score 0):

you should use a param for the event mousedown and mouseup

while mouse down is true you can do setInterval in JS and todo your things.

and when the mouseup is true you can assume that he no longer click the mouse

Comment: do you have an example of how this would look? I'd greatly appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the same, but expanded into a player UI.
I found I needed to add the mouseleave to avoid non-detections.

```
var $wrapper = $('#main');

$('.pageBackOpt32').mousedown(scrollSlowL).mouseup(stopScroll).mouseleave(stopScroll);
$('.pageNextOpt32').mousedown(scrollSlowR).mouseup(stopScroll).mouseleave(stopScroll);
$('.pageRwOpt32').mousedown(scrollFastL).mouseup(stopScroll).mouseleave(stopScroll);        $('.pageFfOpt32').mousedown(scrollFastR).mouseup(stopScroll).mouseleave(stopScroll);

function scrollSlowL() { 
  $wrapper.animate({ scrollLeft: '-=50' }, scrollSlowL); 
}

function scrollSlowR() { 
  $wrapper.animate({ scrollLeft: '+=50' }, scrollSlowR); 
}

function scrollFastL() { 
  $wrapper.animate({ scrollLeft: '-=250' }, scrollFastL); 
}

function scrollFastR() { 
  $wrapper.animate({ scrollLeft: '+=250' }, scrollFastR); 
}

function stopScroll() {
  $wrapper.stop();
}
```