# Need to perform the action of a left click when right mouse button is clicked(Jquery)

Tags: jquery

Does anyone know the jquery code  to perform the action of a left click button when right mouse button is clicked

For Example:
Say I right click on a link , instead of opening a pop up window I need it to go the link's destination . In other wants I need the right click to do the action of a mouse left click .

Tried searching the web , but was of no use . Hence posting this as my last option .

Would really appreciate any help .

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Possible duplicate, Just check out the following link from stackoverflow



 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206203/how-to-distinguish-between-left-and-right-mouse-click-with-jquery

Comment: @viveksalve Both issues are different

Comment: This seems like a bad UI design. Right click is supposed to bring up a menu of actions to perform on the link, you're taking away the user's ability to choose preferred behavior, such as opening the link in a new tab.

Comment: @Barmar Yes. But its one of our clients requirement .

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('a').on('contextmenu', function(e){
    window.location = this.href;
    return false;
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/9AeEd/1/)

Comment: Nope . When I click on the right button I need it to go to the destination directly . Just like how left button click would do

Comment: @jat it does, stackoveflow just removes itself from frames, try http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/9AeEd/1/

Comment: Give me a min . Will try it out . Thank you

Comment: When I paste it on to our server it doest work any idea why ?

Comment: No errors. When I do the right click I just get the popup menu :(

Comment: @jat what browser did you use?

Comment: Is there any headers that I should be including ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#element').mousedown(function(event) {
    if (event.which==3) {
        $('#element').trigger('click');
         break;
       }
});
```