# mouse right click button should perform the action of left click button(jquery)

Tags: jquery

Me and my team are trying to solve this issue .

Does anyone know the jquery code to perform the action of a left click button when right mouse button is clicked

For Example: Say I right click on a link , instead of opening a pop up window I need it to go the link's destination . In other wants I need the right click to do the action of a mouse left click .

Tried searching the web , but was of no use . Hence posting this as my last option .

Would really appreciate any help .

Thanks in advance .

Comment: this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206203/how-to-distinguish-between-left-and-right-mouse-click-with-jquery

Answer (score 0):

Try this, for example (updated):

```
<html>
<body oncontextmenu="return false;">
<a href="#">Test Link</a>
<script src="jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(document).mousedown(function(e)
    {

        if (e.button == 2) //right click
        {
         e.preventDefault();
         e.stopPropagation();
         e.stopImmediatePropagation();
         document.body.style.backgroundColor = "green";
         return false;
        }
        if (e.button == 0)//left click
        {
         e.preventDefault();
         e.stopPropagation();
         e.stopImmediatePropagation();
         document.body.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
         return false;
        }

    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And if you want to prevent the default behavior, use `e.preventDefault();` , `e.stopPropagation();`
`e.stopImmediatePropagation();` before changing the background color.

Comment: Gie me a min . Will give it a try.Thank You

Comment: Wow . It stopped the pop up window from opening when right clicked . But it did not take me to the URL when right clicked .

Comment: You need to implement your own click link behavior (because the code above cancel the default one) - simply put document.location.href='URL here';