# jquery right mouse click div

Tags: jquery, right-click

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to distinguish between left and right mouse click with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206203/how-to-distinguish-between-left-and-right-mouse-click-with-jquery)

How to open context meniu when I click with right mouse click inside the div. Because when I click with right mouse button inside div its fadeouts?

Javascript

```
$("#link").click(function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
   div = $("#mydiv").fadeToggle(300);
});

$("#mydiv").click(function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).click(function(e){
   $('#mydiv').fadeOut(200);
});
```

HTML

```
<a id="link">Click</a>
<div id="mydiv" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;">Hello</div>
```

UPDATE:

Javascript

```
$("#link").click(function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
   div = $("#mydiv").fadeToggle(300);
});

$("#good_buttom").click(function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
   div = $("#hide").fadeToggle(300);
});

$("#mydiv").mousedown(function(e) {
switch (e.which) {
    case 1:
         e.stopPropagation();
         $('#mydiv').fadeOut(200);
        break;
    case 2:
        alert('2');
        break;
    case 3:
        alert('3');
        break;
    default:
        alert('You have a strange mouse');
}
});
```

HTML

```
<a id="link">Click</a>
<div id="mydiv" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;">
    <button id="good_button">Click IT</button>
    <div id="hide" style="display:none;">Show up.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: hi i was looking in this article but didnt understand... I am new in jquery... any help ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`click` is only triggered by left mouse click, while `mousedown` can be triggered by left/middle/right mouse click. So just replace `click` with `mousedown` in your code, and distinguish left/middel/right click by checking `event.which`. Please check [How to distinguish between left and right mouse click with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206203/how-to-distinguish-between-left-and-right-mouse-click-with-jquery) for an example.

BTW: Checking this [link](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_mouse.html) may help you understand the relationship between `click`, `mousedown` and `mouseup` events. And this article: [Javascript Madness: Mouse Events](http://unixpapa.com/js/mouse.html) maybe also helps. As a rule of thumb, it's preferable to handle low-level events like `mousedown` or `mouseup` instead of high-level events like `click` or `dblclick` when you need more control on mouse events.

One more problem is that you put a superfluous "#" before `mydiv` in HTML.

Update: As per your new requirement, you may add the following code to avoid event propagation.

```
$("#good_button").mousedown(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); // avoid triggering its parent
    div = $("#hide").fadeToggle(300);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for reply, I made but not working properly. I have inside div a button, when I want to click on it, the div fadeout... so mousedown is not good ?

Comment: Just found you put an extra "#" before `mydiv` in HTML.

Comment: Please help me... because i am lost..

Comment: I changed thanks :) I just wrote here not copied.. but still not working

Comment: I just updated my answer.

Comment: You had a typo: it's `good_button`, not `good_buttom`.

Comment: Actually in Chrome, Safari, Opera 14+ and IE the middle button also triggers the click event.