# Javascript find out when a link is clicked or opened in another way

Tags: javascript, dom, hyperlink, dom-events

It is quite simple to register a click event and determine if an A-element has been left clicked:

```
window.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    if (event.which !== 1 && event.which !== 2) // left of middle click
        return
    var element = event.target
    if (element.tagName !== 'A') {
        while(element.parentNode) {
            element = element.parentNode
            if (element.tagName === 'A')
                break
        }
        if (element.tagName !== 'A')
            return
    }
    console.log('A-Element was left clicked')
})
```

But my code can't detect it when the user opens a link via `right click`->`open link` or when a link is opened using JavaScript (`window.open()`, `location.href`, ...).

[Is right click a Javascript event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405771/is-right-click-a-javascript-event) doesn't solve my problem, because right clicks themselves don't open links.

So, I'm wondering if there is a good way to find out whenever a link is opened, not only if it is clicked.

I've found [browser.tabs.onUpdated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/onUpdated) which is an event that gets fired whenever a tab is updated. It's extension-exclusive though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is right click a Javascript event?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405771/is-right-click-a-javascript-event)

Comment: You can use the `contextmenu` event to detect when they right-click on it. I don't think there's any event triggered if a JS method is called on the link.

Comment: I don't need an event for when the context menu opens. I need an event for when an entry like "Open link ..." is clicked in a context menu. Or maybe a general even for when a link is being opened.

Comment: There is no such event fired by browsers.

Comment: @Pointy Are you 100% certain?

Comment: The only way to achieve this is to disable the actual right click, and build a custom right click dialog instead, under your own control. Catching the "open link" with JS is simply not possible.

Comment: Also, same question but with jQuery: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15944572/detect-right-clicks-open-in-new-tab-on-link-in-jquery

Answer (score 1):

This might get you close, but it won't handle all cases, such as if they right-click and open in new window or new tab. Basically this sample WON'T work if you open anything in a new tab. But it will work if you open anything in the current tab/window regardless of how it is done (right-click, window.open). Its the `window.onbeforeunload` event. It fires before navigating AWAY from the current page.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    alert("Navigating away...");
};
```

Comment: Thanks. Well it is something that I'll add to my code. But another limitation that I see is that it can't handle protocols other than http and https. It wouldn't work for a mailto link for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm not sure this would be the best answer but with jQuery's [event.which](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_which.asp) it's possible:

```
$('#element').mousedown(function(event) {
    switch (event.which) {
        case 1:
            alert('Left click pressed.');
            break;
        case 2:
            alert('Middle button pressed.');
            break;
        case 3:
            alert('Right click pressed.');
            break;
        default:
            alert('default');
    }
});
```

Snippet below:

```js
$('#link').mousedown(function(event) {
  switch (event.which) {
    case 1:
      alert('Left click pressed.');
      break;
    case 2:
      alert('Middle button pressed.');
      break;
    case 3:
      alert('Right click pressed.');
      break;
    default:
      alert('default');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="whatever.com" id="link">click to find out</a>
```

Comment: This does get you into the handler code when the right mouse button is clicked, but it doesn't intercept a subsequent click on the "Open in new tab" menu entry.

Comment: I didn't tag the question with jquery. Besides that it is just a click handler. The same thing can be done with the code found in the question.

Comment: Forivin pardon me for suggesting an alternative, I'll be here or in my grave when you find the answer you look for.

Comment: Well, if I would have wanted a jquery answer or anything else, the question would be tagged accordingly. Maybe you should read the javscript tag, as it clearly sates "Unless a tag for a framework or library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected for questions with the javascript tag".

Comment: Well, if people read tags instead of question descriptions, your votes would be inverse. I'll take a tag reading course when I get a chance, thanks for the advice.

Comment: No, the problem is that some people don't read question descriptions. I literally had questions going from 0 to -19. Then I added "Please read the whole question before voting" to the top and after a week it went up to 0 again. ... But as I said, your answer wouldn't even be helpful if I had included the jquery tag because I literally use event.which in the code in my question. And catching a right click event wouldn't help, as right clicks do not open links. If you read the question description, you should have known that I'm looking for events other than click.