# Double click instead of single click is required with custom button in IE

Tags: jquery, css, html

Please see the following link:

http://jsfiddle.net/HAaFb/55/

Not sure why this requires a double click and how can it be modified to work with a single click.
The problem happens only in IE it works with Mozilla.

HTML:

```
 <div class="custom-input-file">
        <input type="hidden" value="10000000" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" /> 
        <input class="input-file" type="file" size="1" onchange="readURL(this);" multiple="multiple" name="files[]" /> 
        Choose files
 </div>
```

CSS

```
 .custom-input-file .input-file {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-size: 10000px;
    border: 10000px solid transparent;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    position: absolute;
    right: -1000px;
    top: -1000px;
    cursor: pointer;
}



 .custom-input-file {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}

 .custom-input-file {
  background-color:yellow;
    width: 229px;
    height: 29px;
    font-family: "Tw Cen MT";
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 7px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color:black;
}
```

Comment: It worked fine for me in IE 9. Only one click.

Comment: I don't have a solution, but I **do** experience the same issue in IE10. Single click doesn't work, double click does, every time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17195798/ie-requires-double-click-with-custom-button

Comment: thanks MiniRagnarok but according to the poster "the double click is happening on the text portion of the file upload" for me is happening for the whole button , also no clear (code) solution / workaround is provided in the post so I will keep this fiddle open for now as I think it might be useful in general when/if this is resolved.

Comment: @Athanatos Does the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/plowdawg/HJGFh/) work for you (I don't have IE10 installed on this machine)?

Comment: yes this is a nice workaround thanks, You are using the onclick event on the div so when this is clicked you are triggering a click on the file input. Curious to see if there is another way to get it to work directly using the custom input and why this happens only in IE10.

Comment: @Athanatos I didn't make the fiddle. It's from the link I posted. Glad it worked though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I won't go into the code in the fiddle, as I assume is not exactly what you have on your html (open divs for instance).

Try removing `border: 10000px solid transparent;`

Comment: Thanks that seems to have been the issue it works perfectly now. even in IE 10 ;)