# Make Right CLick becomes Left Click in Ajax Link

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Some people may realize that user often try to open a new window from your website by right clicking and select New Window. However this does not work if the link is AJAX Link like the one mentioning in this site

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2008/01/23/ajax-support-in-the-asp-net-mvc-framework.aspx

The link would eventually becomes

```
<a href="javascript:updateRegion('Individual','/AjaxSample/UpdatePerson/3')">{Name}</a>
```

How do I make right click becomes left click on such link?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to distinguish between left and right mouse click with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206203/how-to-distinguish-between-left-and-right-mouse-click-with-jquery)

Comment: that page explains about how to bind a link with a function that capable to distinguish left and right click. It does not answer how to make a link respond as left click when it is right click. Especially I want those to behave like that when it has javascript in href

Comment: You need to bind an onclick handler which does the action you want THEN RETURNS FALSE to cancel the default click handling.