# NivoSlider - Disable Right Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, nivo-slider

I have been asked to put in place disabling of the right clicks on a website, I've informed them there is so many ways that people can still download the images via Google Images, Cache, Firebug etc etc, but none the less my arguments have gone ignored and they insist this must be done.

Any, I've put in the footer some code that disables right clicking on all elements using `<IMG src="">` this fails to work on NivoSlider, I did change the script to use window load on disabling the right click which works but after slide1 it stops working and I assume this is something to do with changes to the DOM.

JavaScript is by far my weakest point and I'm hoping that someone without to much trouble can either give me a full working solution or something to go on. Thanks in Advance.

They are using NivoSlider with the following trigger:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function($) {
        $(window).load(function() {
            $('#slider').nivoSlider();
        });
     })(jQuery);
</script>
```

And this is the code that I've placed in the footer that fails to work on slide2+

```
<script>
    $(window).load(function() {
        $('img').bind('contextmenu', function(e) {
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're absolutely right with the DOM changes. You need to delegate the event to a parent element.

Try something like this:

```
$('#slider').delegate('img', 'contextmenu', function(e) {
    return false;
});
```

Or this if using jQuery > 1.7:

```
$('#slider').on('contextmenu', 'img', function(e) {
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Excellent, top one worked straight away without any further editing. Thanks very much +1 and accepted.

Answer (score -1):

You might be able to do it by preventing the default behaviour of a right click on the image.

See this answer: [How to distinguish between left and right mouse click with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206203/how-to-distinguish-between-left-and-right-mouse-click-with-jquery)