# Fullcalendar copy/paste an event with right-click on a background-event

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm stuck in my implementation of a copy/paste of events on the latest version of fullcalendar.
I'm using [jquery-contextMenu](https://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/) to display my right-click menu.

I have no problem copying event on right-click:

```
$.contextMenu({
        selector: '.fc-event-resizable', 
        trigger: 'right',
        build: function($trigger, e) {
            return {
                items: {
                    "copy": {name: "Copy", icon: "copy", callback: appt_copy}
                }
            };
        }
    });
```

And in the FullCalendar definition:

```
eventDidMount: function( info )
{
var ev = info.event ;

        info.el.addEventListener( "contextmenu", (jsEvent) =>
        {
        jsEvent.preventDefault() ;
        console.log(ev);
        console.log(jsEvent);
        console.log("RIGHT CLICK OK");
    
            if ( ev.display != "background" )
            appt_sel_right = ev ;
            
        } ) ;
    }
```

It's working, no problem, I can copy the event.

But when I try to paste it to a background event, I can only retrieve the start time of the background event, and not the time of the slot I clicked on. Ex: if my background event is 2pm-6pm and I select the 3pm slot, I can only retrieve "2pm" as the start time.

But the same thing works with a regular left-click, because FullCalendar eventClick is called, and the info.start in eventClick is the time of the slot where I clicked. But info in eventDidMount does not contain the "start" propertie, and a right-click does not trigger eventClick.

Has anyone encountered this problem before? I didn't find any solution working with the last FullCalendar version.

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Maybe this earlier question would help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059291/changing-eventclick-to-occur-on-right-click-in-jquery-fullcalendar-plugin

Comment: Unfortunately no: eventRender no longer exists in the current version of FullCalendar. And the extension mentioned on this page is also noted not working with the current version of FullCalendar.