# Add/Subtract Click Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, jsfiddle, jscript

Can anyone modify this code to [Add by left clicking the number], and [Subtract by right clicking the number]?

This would get rid of the + and - buttons.

I can't figure out how to do it.

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/oxeyeb/57/edit)**

**HTML**

```
<input id="txtNumber" type=text" value="55" style="width:30px" />
<input id="btnAdd" type="button" value="+" onclick="add();" />
<input id="btnSubtract" type="button" value="-" onclick="subtract();" />
```

**Javascript**

```
function add()
{
  var txtNumber = document.getElementById("txtNumber");
  var newNumber = parseInt(txtNumber.value) + 1;
  txtNumber.value = newNumber;
}

function subtract()
{
  var txtNumber = document.getElementById("txtNumber");
  var newNumber = parseInt(txtNumber.value) - 1;
  txtNumber.value = newNumber;
}
```

Comment: Distinguish between left and right click: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2725963/2812842

Comment: Your code seems to work if i return false rather than passing an event param to your context event. http://jsbin.com/oxeyeb/61 Edit: oh.... that's not what you originally had i guess. i hate jsbin for that.. can you include your original code in question?.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good way to do it:

http://jsbin.com/irIwUNi/2/edit

**HTML**

```
<input id="txtNumber" type=text" value="55" 
  style="width:30px" onclick="javascript:add()" 
  oncontextmenu="javascript:subtract(event)" />
```

**Javascript**

```
function add()
{
  var txtNumber = document.getElementById("txtNumber");
  var newNumber = parseInt(txtNumber.value) + 1;
  txtNumber.value = newNumber;
}

function subtract(e)
{
  e.preventDefault();
  var txtNumber = document.getElementById("txtNumber");
  var newNumber = parseInt(txtNumber.value) - 1;
  txtNumber.value = newNumber;
  return false;
}
```

If you just set `add()` to run on click and `subtract()` to run on right click (when the context menu would come up), you can capture the click types you want. Then just pass in `event` to `subtract()` and stop it from doing what it would normally do, i.e. bring up the context menu.

Comment: Yes, prevent the focus event.

Comment: Removing border is easy, just change the style attribute to `style="width:30px;border:0;"`