# Backbone: extend delegateEvents method

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, prototype

In backbone I want to extend  `Backbone.View.prototype.delegateEvents`

```
function (events) {
      if (!(events || (events = getValue(this, 'events')))) return;
      this.undelegateEvents();
      for (var key in events) {
        var method = events[key];
        if (!_.isFunction(method)) method = this[events[key]];
        if (!method) throw new Error('Event "' + events[key] + '" does not exist');
        var match = key.match(eventSplitter);
        var eventName = match[1], selector = match[2];
        method = _.bind(method, this);
        eventName += '.delegateEvents' + this.cid;
        if (selector === '') {
          this.$el.bind(eventName, method);
        } else {
          this.$el.delegate(selector, eventName, method);
        }
      }
    }
```

to add an additional function inside it. Is it a way to extend a prototype without overriding it completely?

In my case, I'm trying to access the `events` arg.

**EDIT:** im trying to achieve something along the lines of this

```
function (events) {
          if (events['rightclick .element']){ App.doStuff() }

          if (!(events || (events = getValue(this, 'events')))) return;
          this.undelegateEvents();
          for (var key in events) {
            var method = events[key];
            if (!_.isFunction(method)) method = this[events[key]];
            if (!method) throw new Error('Event "' + events[key] + '" does not exist');
            var match = key.match(eventSplitter);
            var eventName = match[1], selector = match[2];
            method = _.bind(method, this);
            eventName += '.delegateEvents' + this.cid;
            if (selector === '') {
              this.$el.bind(eventName, method);
            } else {
              this.$el.delegate(selector, eventName, method);
            }
          }
        }
```

Comment: (1) You have to replace the whole thing but you can chain to the standard implementation. (2) `events` isn't always the `events` argument, sometimes it is `this.events` or `this.events()`, hence the first line in the standard implementation. (3) What exactly are you trying to accomplish? There may be an easier way.

Comment: I'm interested on how this can this be chained but, I wanted to add a condition inside of this method for an event (ex: rightclick) from the `events` obj to run some other functions.

Comment: added a simplified example of what I'm trying to do, i want it in the prototype because it need to be applied to all instances of views and can't make a `baseView` in this situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want something at the beginning then you could do this:

```
var delegateEvents = Backbone.View.prototype.delegateEvents;
Backbone.View.prototype.delegateEvents = function(events) {
    // You have to do this here because delegateEvents rarely
    // gets the events from its argument, they almost always
    // come from this.events.
    if(!(events || (events = _(this).result('events'))))
        return;

    // Now do your special stuff.
    if(events['rightclick .element'])
        App.doStuff();

    // And chain it off to the original implementation. We'll
    // always supply the events argument here since we've already
    // done the "is it passed or in this?" logic up above.
    delegateEvents.call(this, events);
};
```

Note that [`_.result`](http://underscorejs.org/#result) does the same thing that the older `getValue` internal function did.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/25Xh9/

Also, there is no `rightclick` event that I'm aware of but [there are ways to detect one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206203/how-to-distinguish-between-left-and-right-mouse-click-with-jquery) if you need to.

Comment: This works perfect, I didn't think to chain the functions like that. Thanks!