# How to add more then one event to the jsf tag graphicImage

Tags: javascript, jsf, events, jsf-2, jsf-2.2

How can I add more then one event to the jsf tag graphicImage? I would like to distinguish between left-mouse, right-mouse and double-click.
The idea was to do something as follows:

```
<h:graphicImage value="/image.jpg" onclick="doClick()" ondblclick="doDblClick()"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'am suggesting use jquery in similar way as it is shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2725963/3401919). This can help you recognize which mouse button was pressed and then call concrete function.