# How to trigger jquery "click" event even when the user clicked "middle button" or right click -> open in a new tab

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript which suppose to mark a notification as read when a user clicks on it.

The javascript is triggered in an `<a>` tag, which after the script returns true, redirects the user to another page with `target="_blank"`;

But if the user uses his middle mouse button, or uses his right click -> open in a new tab,
It will not trigger the event.

I know I can just make a "link" and not allow open in a new tab options, but I rather not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Source of my answer and your question is a duplicate of it : [How to distinguish between left and right mouse click with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206203/how-to-distinguish-between-left-and-right-mouse-click-with-jquery)

Although the answer from that question that would help you :

As of jQuery version 1.1.3, event.which normalizes event.keyCode and event.charCode so you don't have to worry about browser compatibility issues. Documentation on event.which

`event.which` will give 1, 2 or 3 for left, middle and right mouse buttons respectively so:

```
$('#element').mousedown(function(event) {
    switch (event.which) {
        case 1:
            alert('Left Mouse button pressed.');
            break;
        case 2:
            alert('Middle Mouse button pressed.');
            break;
        case 3:
            alert('Right Mouse button pressed.');
            break;
        default:
            alert('You have a strange Mouse!');
    }
});
```

Originally posted from "tinybyte"

Answer (score 1):

use the mousedown event includes which button was pressed

```
$("someTagOrID").on('mousedown', function(e) { 
   if( (e.which === 1) ) {
     alert("left button");
   }if( (e.which === 3) ) {
     alert("right button");
   }else if( (e.which === 2) ) {
      alert("middle button"); 
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `mouse up` event.
Something like this:

```
   <a href="http://www.google.com" onmouseup="alert('a')">link</a>
```